# How to detemine (by code) the assembly corflags?

Tags: .net, assemblies, 32bit-64bit, corflags

I need to write a CorFlags-like application.
If I have a path to assembly file, how to I read its CorFlags?

I specifically need to know if the assembly is Any-CPU or x86 only

I want to avoid loading the assembly using reflection because I need to scan many files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use reflection, you may check out

CCI http://ccimetadata.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=API%20overview or

Mono.Cecil http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil

Comment: CCI worked great. Much faster then using reflection to load all the assemblies

Comment: Better performance is expected, as CCI simply reads metadata from assemblies directly. Reflection will load the whole assemblies which is doomed to be much slower. Luckily CCI has been open sourced and released publicly. :)

Answer (score 10):

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270531/how-to-determine-if-net-assembly-was-built-for-x86-or-x64) link, it describes a similar situation to your query. The accepted answer describes how you can use reflection and [Module.GetPEKind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.module.getpekind(VS.80).aspx). This might help you.

Edit: A bit late, but here's a example:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    using System.Reflection;

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Assembly a = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

            PortableExecutableKinds peKind;
            ImageFileMachine machine;

            a.ManifestModule.GetPEKind(out peKind, out machine);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: GetPEKind fails in a 64 bit process when checking 32 bit assemblies

Answer (score 4):

System.Reflection.Assembly has a whole bunch of things to help you in this.

```
var asmbly = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad("filename");
var PeFlags = asmbly.ManifestModule.GetPEKind();
//PeFlags is effectively CorFlags.
```