# How to check programmatically whether a managed assembly is x86, x64 or AnyCPU?

Tags: c#, .net, compilation, x86-64

I need to determine programmatically whether an assembly is x86, x64 or AnyCPU?  There is an almost identical [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270531/how-to-determine-if-a-net-assembly-was-built-for-x86-or-x64), but the solution that it provides

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(fileName);
PortableExecutableKinds peKind;
ImageFileMachine imageFileMachine;
assembly.ManifestModule.GetPEKind(out peKind, out imageFileMachine);
```

fails when trying to load a 64-bit assembly from a 32-bit process (and vice versa).

Is there a foolproof way of programmatically finding out the compilation type of an assembly?

EDIT: Based on @BenVoigt suggestion, I created a [small command line utility](http://www.angryhacker.com/blog/archive/2012/03/03/how-to-determine-whether-an-assembly-is-32-bit-64.aspx) that checks whether the DLL is managed or not and whether its x86/x64/AnyCPU.  I hope someone finds it useful.

Comment: Have you tried [`ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.reflectiononlyloadfrom.aspx)?

Comment: @BenVoigt That's very likely an answer, not a comment :)

Comment: @BenVoigt I did now and you are absolutely correct.  Make it the answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This question's been covered already:

- [How to Tell if a .NET Assembly Was Compiled as x86, x64 or Any CPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591557/how-to-tell-if-a-net-assembly-was-compiled-as-x86-x64-or-any-cpu)
- [How to determine if a .NET assembly was built for x86 or x64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270531/how-to-determine-if-a-net-assembly-was-built-for-x86-or-x64)
- [How can I get the processor architecture of an assembly dll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186159/how-can-i-get-the-processor-architecture-of-an-assembly-dll)

But the answers are incomplete, suggesting use of `Assembly.LoadFrom`.  That's a terrible idea, since it will run code from the assembly, in addition to failing if the bitness doesn't match your process.

Instead, you should use [`Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.reflectiononlyloadfrom.aspx).  This lets you read the metadata without actually loading any code, and therefore there's no need for the architecture to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Solution how to determinate this just by code without reflection nor thirdparty SW can be found here:
[How to determine if a .NET assembly was built with platform target AnyCPU, AnyCPU Prefer32-bit, x86, x64 without using reflection and third party SW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58025730/how-to-determine-if-a-net-assembly-was-built-with-platform-target-anycpu-anycp/58025731#58025731)