# How do I test an existing managed .NET .dll to see if its 32-bit or 64-bit?

Tags: .net, dll

How do I test an existing managed .NET .dll to see if its 32-bit or 64-bit?

Known dead ends:

- "dumpbin /header" doesn't work, it returns 32-bit for everything (its only looking at the native win32 headers).
- Dependency Walker doesn't work, as its for native win32 .dll's.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Start up Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt, go to the folder your assembly is in type "*corflags.exe*  *assemblyName.dll*" and you should get the following info back

```
Version   : v4.0.30319
CLR Header: 2.5
PE        : PE32
CorFlags  : 1
ILONLY    : 1
32BIT     : 0
Signed    : 0
```

Comment: For VS 2012, CorFlags shows 32BITREQ(UIRED) and 32BITPREF(ERRED). See http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2012/04/04/what-anycpu-really-means-as-of-net-4-5-and-visual-studio-11.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164699%28v=vs.110%29.aspx .

Answer (score 1):

See [How to determine if a .NET assembly was built for x86 or x64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270531/how-to-determine-if-a-net-assembly-was-built-for-x86-or-x64)

Comment: This question also gives the answer, but it doesn't include the keywords "managed", "32-bit" or "64-bit", so its a bit difficult to quickly navigate to it.