# Could not load assembly 64bit machine

Tags: asp.net

I am getting the following error if I try to run the ASP.NET 4.0 website in a 64 bit machine with Enable 32 bit Applications flag set to false. (I have to set that to False, If I set it to true its working fine).
**> "Could not load file or assembly 'Common.BL' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.**

And in the project properties the Target of Build is set to Any CPU.

Still I am getting the same error.

Can you guys please help me resolving this error. Anyhelp would be appreciated.

Thanks.
Sameer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure Common.BL is 64 bit. You can check this fairly easily. Check this out for help:

[How to determine if a .NET assembly was built for x86 or x64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270531/how-to-determine-if-a-net-assembly-was-built-for-x86-or-x64)

Let's use that as a starting point, post the results. If it is a 32 bit and you are on IIS 6, then ALL of IIS must be set to run in 32 bit mode. 
If you are in IIS 7 then you can set a specific app pool to run in 32 bit mode. Ensure you compile your code for 32 bit though.

Comment: @Randolpho..Yes The Common.BL has the following properties       Version : v4.0.30319                                                  CLR Header : 2.5                                                      PE : PE32                                                            CorFlags : 3                                                        ILONLY : 1                                                           32 BIT : 1                                                           Signed : 0

Comment: then you need to do what I mentioned above depending on your IIS version.

Comment: If you are running IIS 6 see: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/894435  for iis 7 see: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/201/32-bit-mode-worker-processes/  or for an app pool level (not server level) see: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rakkimk/archive/2007/11/03/iis7-running-32-bit-and-64-bit-asp-net-versions-at-the-same-time-on-different-worker-processes.aspx

Comment: what specifically fixed your issue?

Answer (score 1):

I'd focus on the "or one of its dependencies" portion of the error. Are you referencing a 32-bit assembly or one compiled for a different platform?

Comment: No I am using the 64 bit version of ODP.NET

Comment: @Randolpho..Yes The Common.BL has the following properties       Version : v4.0.30319                                                  CLR Header : 2.5                                                      PE : PE32                                                            CorFlags : 3                                                        ILONLY : 1                                                           32 BIT : 1                                                           Signed : 0

Comment: If it is the problem referencing the 32 bit, How can I resolve it for 64 bit..please do let me know..THanks