# How to build 32 bits C++ CLR project in 64 bit OS

Tags: c++, .net, clr, 32bit-64bit

My OS is Windows 7, 64 bits.

In Visual Studio, I'm trying to build this C++ CLR project as 32 bits, but after I build it, when I run Dependency Walker on it, every system dll it uses (for example, `kernel32`) is of 64 bit, thus giving the error "Modules with different CPU types were found".

I've already set the platform option to Win32 (btw, is this right? I expected x86, is Win32 equivalent?).
I also checked that in `Linker->Advanced->Target Machine` is equal to `MachineX86`.

Is there anything else I could do to build it targeting 32 bits.

`EDIT 1:` Since HansPassant questioned the reliability of Dependency Walker, I checked the bitness using `corflags`.
Results are these:

```
Version   : v4.0.30319
CLR Header: 2.5
PE        : PE32
CorFlags  : 0x10
ILONLY    : 0
32BITREQ  : 0
32BITPREF : 0
Signed    : 0
```

According to this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1002800/796608) answer, apparently the dll is targeting "Any CPU".

I targeted 32 bits already, why is this happening?

Comment: Are you using the 32-bit version of Dependency Walker, and not the 64-bit version?

Comment: You'll need to stop using Depends, it has not been maintained in a very long time.  It is particularly unsuitable to look at .NET assemblies.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm using the 64 bit version. Are you saying it does make a difference?

Comment: @HansPassant Ok, do you know any alternative to check the bitness of a dll?

Comment: Why don't you just debug the code?  You'll find out *really* quickly.

Comment: @Erandros - Yes it makes a difference.  If your module is 32 bit, then the 64-bit version assumes that the 32-bit module is in error.  Use the 32-bit version of Depends to view 32-bit modules.