# Appcrash while running the windows application after installing the setup

Tags: c#, 32bit-64bit, windows, crash

I have developed a windows application in visual studio 2012 and deployed the application using Installshield. When I install the application in 32-bit system it works fine, but while I install in 64-bit system, it installs fine but after installing the application is not opening throwing and error that,

Problem Signature:

Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
Application Name: sappln.exe
Fault Module Name: KERNALBASE.DLL
and more it goes on..

In configuration Manager, I have specified Release -> Any CPU
Can anyone give some solutions to avoid this error?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Some more details of the error might be useful. Can you add what you have described as '..and more it goes on'?

Comment: In a short it says- Application has stopped working

Comment: My money is on fact that you reference COM library (interop) that has just 32 bit alignment; or you compile your code explicitly to x32 - compilation should target MSIL if you want to deploy same binaries both to x32 and x64.

Comment: how to target the compilation to MSIL, according to me it wil be done automatically by the .net

Comment: By default it is MSIL, but you can set it otherwise. Also all you dependencies should be MSIL - check your bin folder if is that so (reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270531/how-to-determine-if-a-net-assembly-was-built-for-x86-or-x64)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using libaries that can't run on x64 platforms. What libaries are you using?

Also check if your program does anything "special" upon startup.

This should keep you out.

Good luck!

Comment: i have so many libraries totally 9 lib's... Can we change that inorder to work at 64-bit

Comment: can anyone say what to do?

Comment: Did you write the libaries yourself?

Comment: how can we write? I am speaking about dll's

Comment: DLL is also a libary. These DLL Files are you the writer of those or did you download them ? Post the name of all the DLL files.

Comment: i have downloaded them, sapnco.dll, sapnco_utils.dll,DBReader.dll,INIFileParser.dll,SAP.Connector.dll,SAPConnectionManager.dll,Spire.DataExport.dll

Comment: Good. One of more of these libaries does not work on x64. So you have to go the website of these DLL files to check if they have a x64 version.

Comment: ok thanks i wil check with that.... so after getting the 64bit version i wanna replace that dll's right?

Comment: No you cannot just replace. Then it won't work on 32 bit. You have to change your code so it checks for the Architecture. Else compile two different versions - one with X64 and one with X32.

Comment: yeah yeah!! I gonna generate setup fro 2 versions separately so, i wil replace the dll for 64-bit setup alone... Thanks for your initiative mate, if it works I wil comeback and post here :)

Comment: Glad I could help. Go Go Go Go !