# Run C#.NET Application with different Processor Architecture of Orcale.DataAccess

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I have Oracle Client 12 installed on my 32bit client (tnsping from client cmd):

```
TNS Ping Utility for 32-bit Windows: Version 12.1.0.2.0
```

And Oracle Client 12 installed on my 64bit Windows 2012R2 server (tnsping from server cmd):

```
TNS Ping Utility for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.1.0.2.0
```

When I compile my C#.NET application and publish it to my server I get the following exception:

> Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client

In the `bin` directory of my application on my server the `Oracle.DataAcces.dll` is still `2.112.3.0` and not `2.121.2.0` (which is installed on my client and on my server). 
Why is there the wrong `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` file on my server?

I have set the *Enable 32-bit Application* bool to **True** in my application pool settings.

How can I get rid of this exception?

Comment: Life will be much easier if you use [Managed ODP.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/)

Comment: Are you sure that your reference in the project is to `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` version `2.121.2.0`

Comment: No it isn't. Where can I change this @codroipo?

Comment: I have removed the old reference and added the new one. Uploaded the porject and on my server the version is now correct but I still get the same error @codroipo ...

Comment: Remove attribute `processorArchitecture=...` from reference in your "*.csproj" file, See details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659341/the-provider-is-not-compatible-with-the-version-of-oracle-client#25412992

Comment: I have it updated now and I get the following exception now @Wernfried: `Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)`

Comment: Your application tries to load version **4**.121.2.0. If you like to load version 2.x you must set your compiler target to something lower than `.NET Framework 4`, e.g. `.NET Framework 3.5`

Comment: I have reuploaded the application and get an exception with incorrect format @Wernfried: `Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.`

Comment: Version of TNS Ping utility is not necessarily the same as version of `Oracle.DataAcces.dll`. Check it carefully with "Properties" in File Explorer.

Comment: They both have the version number `4.121.2.0` (on my client and on my server in the bin directory)

Comment: @Hack4Life What is your project target? x86, x64 or AnyCPU? What is the target platform of the `Oracle.DataAcces.dll` you are referencing? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270531/how-to-determine-if-a-net-assembly-was-built-for-x86-or-x64)

Comment: AnyCPU. My client is running on Windows 7 professional 32bit and on my server is Windows Server 2012R2 64bit. I have enabled the 32-bit Applications in my Applicationpool settings @codroipo

Comment: @Hack4Life An AnyCPU application in 64-bit environment will be run as x64, doesn't matter if you `enabled 32-bit application in appPool`. If you want it to run as 32 bit application you have to set the target platform as x86 and recompile

Comment: Ok thanks, i will try it later that week when I'm back at the office @codroipo