# How to determine if it is a .net core assembly or a framework assembly with code

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, assemblies

I am looking for a way to look at an assembly in c# and determine if it is a .net core assembly or a framework assembly. In addition, if it is a 64bit or 32bit.

The assembly will not be running.

I am using it to identify the type of worker process I need to create to process the assembly.

Comment: Did you check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270531/how-to-determine-if-a-net-assembly-was-built-for-x86-or-x64 ?

Comment: I need to be able to do it with c#. So powershell isn't an option.

Answer (score 1):

C# not tested with .net works with .net core... Also checkout System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var framework = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()?.GetCustomAttribute<TargetFrameworkAttribute>()?.FrameworkName;
        Console.WriteLine($"{assembly.GetName().ProcessorArchitecture.ToString()} - {framework}");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Check out: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2018/Apr/12/Getting-the-NET-Core-Runtime-Version-in-a-Running-Application

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell

```
[reflection.assemblyname]::GetAssemblyName("") | fl
```