# C# reflection: how to tell if a DLL is .NET core or .NET framework?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-framework-version

Using C# reflection to inspect the metadata of an arbitrary .NET DLL, how do I find out if it is written in .NET core (e.g. .NET 6.0 or 7.0) or .NET Framework (e.g. .NET Framework 4.7.2)?

The reason I ask this question, is that I am creating a user interface application used to load existing .NET DLLs, examine them using reflection, and do something.

I have created two versions of this UI, one in **.NET core**, one in **.NET Framework**. I intend to let the **.NET Core** UI to only open DLLs written in **.NET core**, and the **.NET Framework** UI to only open DLLs written in **.NET Framework**. This way I can avoid unexpected strange exceptions due to incompatibility.

For this to happen, when the user uses the **.NET Core** version of my app to select a DLL written in **.NET Framework**, I want the app to raise an error message and refues to proceed. Vice versa. This requires my code to tell what the DLL is written in.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine if it is a .net core assembly or a framework assembly with code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54057841/how-to-determine-if-it-is-a-net-core-assembly-or-a-framework-assembly-with-code)

Comment: Assemblies against each .NET Framework versions have some unique patterns (1.0-4.8.x), but that alone is a lengthy answer. .NET Core 1.0-.NET 7/8 is simpler, but still a lengthy post is needed. Even the answers from the linked old threads contain all kinds of misinformation. How accurate an answer do you need? I assume most people might just pick a partial answer and end the discussion.

Comment: Assemblies aren't written "in" frameworks. They may target specific frameworks; they may not (it's possible to write a "pure" assembly that will load in any version of .NET whatsoever, although it couldn't contain much interesting code). If the question is whether a particular assembly will work for a particular framework (load and/or execute), that's more subtle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3460982/determine-net-framework-version-for-dll)

`tar.FrameworkDisplayName` would be your runtime version:

```
var tar = (TargetFrameworkAttribute)Assembly
    .LoadFrom("yoursAssembly.dll")
    .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TargetFrameworkAttribute)).First();
```

Comment: You might be surprised that many existing assemblies out there don’t have this attribute.

Comment: How would that come? Is this attribute only included in the compiled .DLLs that target a newer .NET / .NETFramework version?

Comment: There are two decades of C# compilers from Microsoft and other vendors, so you have a lot to learn from.