# How to find if a native DLL file is compiled as x64 or x86?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, 64-bit, x86-64

I want to determine if a native assembly is complied as x64 or x86 from a managed code application ([C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29)).

I think it must be somewhere in the PE header since the OS loader needs to know this information, but I couldn't find it. Of course I prefer to do it in managed code, but if it necessary, I can use native C++.

Comment: To be clear, the dll in question is also a .Net assembly? You say native DLL in title of the post, but native assembly in the description... if you are still actively looking at this post from 09 :)

Comment: You might also want to check out this one: [check-if-unmanaged-dll-is-32-bit-or-64-bit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001404/check-if-unmanaged-dll-is-32-bit-or-64-bit).

Comment: Also related: [How can I determine for which platform an executable is compiled?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/197951/1364007)

Answer (score 151):

You can use [DUMPBIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1h23y6c%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) too. Use the `/headers` or `/all` flag and its the first file header listed.

```
dumpbin /headers cv210.dll
```

#### 64-bit

```
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file cv210.dll

PE signature found

File Type: DLL

FILE HEADER VALUES
            8664 machine (x64)
               6 number of sections
        4BBAB813 time date stamp Tue Apr 06 12:26:59 2010
               0 file pointer to symbol table
               0 number of symbols
              F0 size of optional header
            2022 characteristics
                   Executable
                   Application can handle large (>2GB) addresses
                   DLL
```

#### 32-bit

```
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file acrdlg.dll

PE signature found

File Type: DLL

FILE HEADER VALUES
             14C machine (x86)
               5 number of sections
        467AFDD2 time date stamp Fri Jun 22 06:38:10 2007
               0 file pointer to symbol table
               0 number of symbols
              E0 size of optional header
            2306 characteristics
                   Executable
                   Line numbers stripped
                   32 bit word machine
                   Debug information stripped
                   DLL
```

'find' can make life slightly easier:

```
dumpbin /headers cv210.dll |find "machine"
        8664 machine (x64)
```

Comment: DUMPBIN doesn't work for .NET EXEs. I have a 64-bit .NET EXE that DUMPBIN says is 32-bit ("14C machine (x86)"), but corflags says is Any CPU ("PE: PE32, 32BIT: 0"). Dependency Walker also misdiagnoses it.

Comment: It required `mspdb100.dll`:(

Comment: @Altaveron I had the same issue, but resolved it by copying the DLL file `mspdb100.dll` to the folder where `dumpbin.exe` is located. `DUMPBIN` can run after that. For me, the EXE is at `<Visual Studio Install folder>\VC\bin` and the DLL is at `<Visual Studio Install folder>\Common7\IDE`.

Comment: DUMPBIN is available from Visual Studio command prompt for those with Visual Studio installed

Comment: Cool. That was my issue. (rg = ripgrep is now available on windows)
I used this on the VS terminal:
`dumpbin.exe /headers .\ImGuiExtension.dll | rg machine`

Comment: `AA64 machine (ARM64)` is added now.

Answer (score 69):

This [trick](https://superuser.com/questions/358434/how-to-check-if-a-binary-is-32-or-64-bit-on-windows) works and requires only Notepad.

Open the dll file using a text editor (like Notepad) and find the first occurrence of the string `PE`. The following character defines if the dll is 32 or 64 bits.

### 32 bits:

```
PE  L
```

### 64 bits:

```
PE  d†
```

Answer (score 60):

There is an easy way to do this with [CorFlags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164699%28VS.80%29.aspx). Open the Visual Studio Command Prompt and type "corflags [your assembly]". You'll get something like this:

> c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC>corflags
>   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Data.dll"
>
> Microsoft (R) .NET Framework CorFlags
>   Conversion Tool.  Version  3.5.21022.8
>   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.
>   All rights reserved.
>
> Version   : v2.0.50727
>   CLR Header: 2.5
>   PE        : PE32
>   CorFlags  : 24
>   ILONLY    : 0
>   32BIT     : 0
>   Signed    : 1

You're looking at PE and 32BIT specifically.

- *Any CPU*:

  PE:    PE32
  32BIT: 0
- *x86*:

  PE:    PE32
  32BIT: 1
- x64:

  PE:    PE32+
  32BIT: 0

Comment: @BLogan you should look at my comment to Steven Behnke above. I'm aware of the corflags utility but it doesn't work on native assemblies.

Comment: What Corflags outputs changed in latter versions (Windows SDK 8 or higher).  Now instead of 32BIT it has 32BITREQUIRED and 32BITPREFERRED.  See description in CorHdr.h located C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\CorHdr.h.  From what I can tell 32BITREQUIRED replaces 32BIT.  Also see answer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767010/where-can-i-find-a-reference-for-what-every-bit-of-the-corflags-value-means).

Answer (score 29):

The `Magic` field of the `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER` (though there is nothing optional about the header in Windows executable images (DLL/EXE files)) will tell you the architecture of the PE.

Here's an example of grabbing the architecture from a file.

```
public static ushort GetImageArchitecture(string filepath) {
    using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream(filepath, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read))
    using (var reader = new System.IO.BinaryReader(stream)) {
        //check the MZ signature to ensure it's a valid Portable Executable image
        if (reader.ReadUInt16() != 23117) 
            throw new BadImageFormatException("Not a valid Portable Executable image", filepath);

        // seek to, and read, e_lfanew then advance the stream to there (start of NT header)
        stream.Seek(0x3A, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Current); 
        stream.Seek(reader.ReadUInt32(), System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);

        // Ensure the NT header is valid by checking the "PE\0\0" signature
        if (reader.ReadUInt32() != 17744)
            throw new BadImageFormatException("Not a valid Portable Executable image", filepath);

        // seek past the file header, then read the magic number from the optional header
        stream.Seek(20, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Current); 
        return reader.ReadUInt16();
    }
}
```

The only two architecture constants at the moment are:

```
0x10b - PE32
0x20b - PE32+
```

Cheers

**UPDATE**
It's been a while since I posted this answer, yet I still see that it gets a few upvotes now and again so I figured it was worth updating. I wrote a way to get the architecture of a `Portable Executable` image, which also checks to see if it was compiled as `AnyCPU`. Unfortunately the answer is in C++, but it shouldn't be too hard to port to C# if you have a few minutes to look up the structures in `WinNT.h`. If people are interested I'll write a port in C#, but unless people actually want it I wont spend much time stressing about it.

```
#include <Windows.h>

#define MKPTR(p1,p2) ((DWORD_PTR)(p1) + (DWORD_PTR)(p2))

typedef enum _pe_architecture {
    PE_ARCHITECTURE_UNKNOWN = 0x0000,
    PE_ARCHITECTURE_ANYCPU  = 0x0001,
    PE_ARCHITECTURE_X86     = 0x010B,
    PE_ARCHITECTURE_x64     = 0x020B
} PE_ARCHITECTURE;

LPVOID GetOffsetFromRva(IMAGE_DOS_HEADER *pDos, IMAGE_NT_HEADERS *pNt, DWORD rva) {
    IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER *pSecHd = IMAGE_FIRST_SECTION(pNt);
    for(unsigned long i = 0; i < pNt->FileHeader.NumberOfSections; ++i, ++pSecHd) {
        // Lookup which section contains this RVA so we can translate the VA to a file offset
        if (rva >= pSecHd->VirtualAddress && rva < (pSecHd->VirtualAddress + pSecHd->Misc.VirtualSize)) {
            DWORD delta = pSecHd->VirtualAddress - pSecHd->PointerToRawData;
            return (LPVOID)MKPTR(pDos, rva - delta);
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

PE_ARCHITECTURE GetImageArchitecture(void *pImageBase) {
    // Parse and validate the DOS header
    IMAGE_DOS_HEADER *pDosHd = (IMAGE_DOS_HEADER*)pImageBase;
    if (IsBadReadPtr(pDosHd, sizeof(pDosHd->e_magic)) || pDosHd->e_magic != IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE)
        return PE_ARCHITECTURE_UNKNOWN;

    // Parse and validate the NT header
    IMAGE_NT_HEADERS *pNtHd = (IMAGE_NT_HEADERS*)MKPTR(pDosHd, pDosHd->e_lfanew);
    if (IsBadReadPtr(pNtHd, sizeof(pNtHd->Signature)) || pNtHd->Signature != IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE)
        return PE_ARCHITECTURE_UNKNOWN;

    // First, naive, check based on the 'Magic' number in the Optional Header.
    PE_ARCHITECTURE architecture = (PE_ARCHITECTURE)pNtHd->OptionalHeader.Magic;

    // If the architecture is x86, there is still a possibility that the image is 'AnyCPU'
    if (architecture == PE_ARCHITECTURE_X86) {
        IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY comDirectory = pNtHd->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_COM_DESCRIPTOR];
        if (comDirectory.Size) {
            IMAGE_COR20_HEADER *pClrHd = (IMAGE_COR20_HEADER*)GetOffsetFromRva(pDosHd, pNtHd, comDirectory.VirtualAddress);
            // Check to see if the CLR header contains the 32BITONLY flag, if not then the image is actually AnyCpu
            if ((pClrHd->Flags & COMIMAGE_FLAGS_32BITREQUIRED) == 0)
                architecture = PE_ARCHITECTURE_ANYCPU;
        }
    }

    return architecture;
}
```

The function accepts a pointer to an in-memory PE image (so you can choose your poison on how to get it their; memory-mapping or reading the whole thing into memory...whatever).

Comment: Very interesting but when I have an application compiled with Any CPU, the result is 0x10B. This is wrong because my application is run in a x64 system. Is there any other flag to check?

Comment: AnyCPU means just that: AnyCPU, so it's listed as 0x10B in the PE header for backwards compatibility with 32-bit. To check the difference between that and straight 32-bit, you'd need to find out where CorFlags gets its `32BIT` flag from in the PE, I don't know off the top of my head.

Comment: @Samuel Updated to check the AnyCPU flag.

Comment: that C# code works in a 64 bit process when checking 32 bit assemblies ? For example, Module.GetPEKind http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.module.getpekind%28VS.80%29.aspx fails

Comment: It should work fine, it's just doing basic IO and interpreting what it reads, nothing too fancy @Kiquenet

Answer (score 14):

For an unmanaged DLL file, you need to first check if it is a 16-bit DLL file (hopefully not).
Then check the `IMAGE\_FILE_HEADER.Machine` field.

[Someone else](https://web.archive.org/web/20151001165014/http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Development/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.tools/2006-12/msg00011.html) took the time to work this out already, so I will just repeat here:

> To distinguish between a 32-bit and 64-bit PE file, you should check
> `IMAGE\_FILE\_HEADER.Machine` field. Based on the Microsoft PE and COFF
> specification below, I have listed out
> all the possible values for this field:
> [http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/c/5/9c5b2167-8017-4bae-9fde-d599bac8184a/pecoff_v8.doc](https://web.archive.org/web/20070330083705/https://download.microsoft.com/download/9/c/5/9c5b2167-8017-4bae-9fde-d599bac8184a/pecoff_v8.doc)
>
> | const | value | descr |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_UNKNOWN | 0x0 | The contents of this field are assumed to be applicable to any machine type |
> | IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_AM33 | 0x1d3 | Matsushita AM33 |
> | **IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_AMD64** | **0x8664** | **x64** |
> | IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_ARM | 0x1c0 | ARM little endian |
> | IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_EBC | 0xebc | EFI byte code |
> | **IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_I386** | **0x14c** | **Intel 386 or later processors and compatible processors** |
> | IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_IA64 | 0x200 | Intel Itanium processor family |
> | IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_M32R | 0x9041 | Mitsubishi M32R little endian |
> | IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_MIPS16 | 0x266 | MIPS16 |
> | IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_MIPSFPU | 0x366 | MIPS with FPU |
> | IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_MIPSFPU16 | 0x466 | MIPS16 with FPU |
> | IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_POWERPC | 0x1f0 | Power PC little endian |
> | IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_POWERPCFP | 0x1f1 | Power PC with floating point support |
> | IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_R4000 | 0x166 | MIPS little endian |
> | IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_SH3 | 0x1a2 | Hitachi SH3 |
> | IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_SH3DSP | 0x1a3 | Hitachi SH3 DSP |
> | IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_SH4 | 0x1a6 | Hitachi SH4 |
> | IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_SH5 | 0x1a8 | Hitachi SH5 |
> | IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_THUMB | 0x1c2 | Thumb |
> | IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_WCEMIPSV2 | 0x169 | MIPS little-endian WCE v2 |
>
> Yes, you may check
> `IMAGE\_FILE\_MACHINE_AMD64|IMAGE\_FILE\_MACHINE_IA64` for 64bit and `IMAGE\_FILE\_MACHINE_I386` for 32bit.

Comment: your second link is dead :s

Comment: More values: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format#machine-types and https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Windows_Executable_Files#COFF_Header because "_64 bit_" can also not only mean ARM or Itanium, but also PowerPC, Alpha or RISCV.

Answer (score 5):

You can find a [C# sample implementation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001404/check-if-unmanaged-dll-is-32-bit-or-64-bit/1002672#1002672) for the `IMAGE_FILE_HEADER` solution

Answer (score 4):

I rewrote [c++ solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9783522/2531187) in first answer in powershell script. Script can determine this types of .exe and .dll files:

```
#Description       C# compiler switch             PE type       machine corflags
#MSIL              /platform:anycpu (default)     PE32  x86     ILONLY
#MSIL 32 bit pref  /platform:anycpu32bitpreferred PE32  x86     ILONLY | 32BITREQUIRED | 32BITPREFERRED
#x86 managed       /platform:x86                  PE32  x86     ILONLY | 32BITREQUIRED
#x86 mixed         n/a                            PE32  x86     32BITREQUIRED
#x64 managed       /platform:x64                  PE32+ x64     ILONLY
#x64 mixed         n/a                            PE32+ x64  
#ARM managed       /platform:arm                  PE32  ARM     ILONLY
#ARM mixed         n/a                            PE32  ARM
```

this solution has some advantages over corflags.exe and loading assembly via Assembly.Load in C# - you will never get BadImageFormatException or message about invalid header.

```
function GetActualAddressFromRVA($st, $sec, $numOfSec, $dwRVA)
{
    [System.UInt32] $dwRet = 0;
    for($j = 0; $j -lt $numOfSec; $j++)   
    {   
        $nextSectionOffset = $sec + 40*$j;
        $VirtualSizeOffset = 8;
        $VirtualAddressOffset = 12;
        $SizeOfRawDataOffset = 16;
        $PointerToRawDataOffset = 20;

    $Null = @(
        $curr_offset = $st.BaseStream.Seek($nextSectionOffset + $VirtualSizeOffset, [System.IO.SeekOrigin]::Begin);        
        [System.UInt32] $VirtualSize = $b.ReadUInt32();
        [System.UInt32] $VirtualAddress = $b.ReadUInt32();
        [System.UInt32] $SizeOfRawData = $b.ReadUInt32();
        [System.UInt32] $PointerToRawData = $b.ReadUInt32();        

        if ($dwRVA -ge $VirtualAddress -and $dwRVA -lt ($VirtualAddress + $VirtualSize)) {
            $delta = $VirtualAddress - $PointerToRawData;
            $dwRet = $dwRVA - $delta;
            return $dwRet;
        }
        );
    }
    return $dwRet;
}

function Get-Bitness2([System.String]$path, $showLog = $false)
{
    $Obj = @{};
    $Obj.Result = '';
    $Obj.Error = $false;

    $Obj.Log = @(Split-Path -Path $path -Leaf -Resolve);

    $b = new-object System.IO.BinaryReader([System.IO.File]::Open($path,[System.IO.FileMode]::Open,[System.IO.FileAccess]::Read, [System.IO.FileShare]::Read));
    $curr_offset = $b.BaseStream.Seek(0x3c, [System.IO.SeekOrigin]::Begin)
    [System.Int32] $peOffset = $b.ReadInt32();
    $Obj.Log += 'peOffset ' + "{0:X0}" -f $peOffset;

    $curr_offset = $b.BaseStream.Seek($peOffset, [System.IO.SeekOrigin]::Begin);
    [System.UInt32] $peHead = $b.ReadUInt32();

    if ($peHead -ne 0x00004550) {
        $Obj.Error = $true;
        $Obj.Result = 'Bad Image Format';
        $Obj.Log += 'cannot determine file type (not x64/x86/ARM) - exit with error';
    };

    if ($Obj.Error)
    {
        $b.Close();
        Write-Host ($Obj.Log | Format-List | Out-String);
        return $false;
    };

    [System.UInt16] $machineType = $b.ReadUInt16();
    $Obj.Log += 'machineType ' + "{0:X0}" -f $machineType;

    [System.UInt16] $numOfSections = $b.ReadUInt16();
    $Obj.Log += 'numOfSections ' + "{0:X0}" -f $numOfSections;
    if (($machineType -eq 0x8664) -or ($machineType -eq 0x200)) { $Obj.Log += 'machineType: x64'; }
    elseif ($machineType -eq 0x14c)                             { $Obj.Log += 'machineType: x86'; }
    elseif ($machineType -eq 0x1c0)                             { $Obj.Log += 'machineType: ARM'; }
    else{
        $Obj.Error = $true;
        $Obj.Log += 'cannot determine file type (not x64/x86/ARM) - exit with error';
    };

    if ($Obj.Error) {
        $b.Close();
        Write-Output ($Obj.Log | Format-List | Out-String);
        return $false;
    };

    $curr_offset = $b.BaseStream.Seek($peOffset+20, [System.IO.SeekOrigin]::Begin);
    [System.UInt16] $sizeOfPeHeader = $b.ReadUInt16();

    $coffOffset = $peOffset + 24;#PE header size is 24 bytes
    $Obj.Log += 'coffOffset ' + "{0:X0}" -f $coffOffset;

    $curr_offset = $b.BaseStream.Seek($coffOffset, [System.IO.SeekOrigin]::Begin);#+24 byte magic number
    [System.UInt16] $pe32 = $b.ReadUInt16();         
    $clr20headerOffset = 0;
    $flag32bit = $false;
    $Obj.Log += 'pe32 magic number: ' + "{0:X0}" -f $pe32;
    $Obj.Log += 'size of optional header ' + ("{0:D0}" -f $sizeOfPeHeader) + " bytes";

    #COMIMAGE_FLAGS_ILONLY               =0x00000001,
    #COMIMAGE_FLAGS_32BITREQUIRED        =0x00000002,
    #COMIMAGE_FLAGS_IL_LIBRARY           =0x00000004,
    #COMIMAGE_FLAGS_STRONGNAMESIGNED     =0x00000008,
    #COMIMAGE_FLAGS_NATIVE_ENTRYPOINT    =0x00000010,
    #COMIMAGE_FLAGS_TRACKDEBUGDATA       =0x00010000,
    #COMIMAGE_FLAGS_32BITPREFERRED       =0x00020000,

    $COMIMAGE_FLAGS_ILONLY        = 0x00000001;
    $COMIMAGE_FLAGS_32BITREQUIRED = 0x00000002;
    $COMIMAGE_FLAGS_32BITPREFERRED = 0x00020000;

    $offset = 96;
    if ($pe32 -eq 0x20b) {
        $offset = 112;#size of COFF header is bigger for pe32+
    }     

    $clr20dirHeaderOffset = $coffOffset + $offset + 14*8;#clr directory header offset + start of section number 15 (each section is 8 byte long);
    $Obj.Log += 'clr20dirHeaderOffset ' + "{0:X0}" -f $clr20dirHeaderOffset;
    $curr_offset = $b.BaseStream.Seek($clr20dirHeaderOffset, [System.IO.SeekOrigin]::Begin);
    [System.UInt32] $clr20VirtualAddress = $b.ReadUInt32();
    [System.UInt32] $clr20Size = $b.ReadUInt32();
    $Obj.Log += 'clr20VirtualAddress ' + "{0:X0}" -f $clr20VirtualAddress;
    $Obj.Log += 'clr20SectionSize ' + ("{0:D0}" -f $clr20Size) + " bytes";

    if ($clr20Size -eq 0) {
        if ($machineType -eq 0x1c0) { $Obj.Result = 'ARM native'; }
        elseif ($pe32 -eq 0x10b)    { $Obj.Result = '32-bit native'; }
        elseif($pe32 -eq 0x20b)     { $Obj.Result = '64-bit native'; }

       $b.Close();   
       if ($Obj.Result -eq '') { 
            $Obj.Error = $true;
            $Obj.Log += 'Unknown type of file';
       }
       else { 
            if ($showLog) { Write-Output ($Obj.Log | Format-List | Out-String); };
            return $Obj.Result;
       }
    };

    if ($Obj.Error) {
        $b.Close();
        Write-Host ($Obj.Log | Format-List | Out-String);
        return $false;
    };

    [System.UInt32]$sectionsOffset = $coffOffset + $sizeOfPeHeader;
    $Obj.Log += 'sectionsOffset ' + "{0:X0}" -f $sectionsOffset;
    $realOffset = GetActualAddressFromRVA $b $sectionsOffset $numOfSections $clr20VirtualAddress;
    $Obj.Log += 'real IMAGE_COR20_HEADER offset ' + "{0:X0}" -f $realOffset;
    if ($realOffset -eq 0) {
        $Obj.Error = $true;
        $Obj.Log += 'cannot find COR20 header - exit with error';
        $b.Close();
        return $false;
    };

    if ($Obj.Error) {
        $b.Close();
        Write-Host ($Obj.Log | Format-List | Out-String);
        return $false;
    };

    $curr_offset = $b.BaseStream.Seek($realOffset + 4, [System.IO.SeekOrigin]::Begin);
    [System.UInt16] $majorVer = $b.ReadUInt16();
    [System.UInt16] $minorVer = $b.ReadUInt16();
    $Obj.Log += 'IMAGE_COR20_HEADER version ' + ("{0:D0}" -f $majorVer) + "." + ("{0:D0}" -f $minorVer);

    $flagsOffset = 16;#+16 bytes - flags field
    $curr_offset = $b.BaseStream.Seek($realOffset + $flagsOffset, [System.IO.SeekOrigin]::Begin);
    [System.UInt32] $flag32bit = $b.ReadUInt32();
    $Obj.Log += 'CorFlags: ' + ("{0:X0}" -f $flag32bit);

#Description       C# compiler switch             PE type       machine corflags
#MSIL              /platform:anycpu (default)     PE32  x86     ILONLY
#MSIL 32 bit pref  /platform:anycpu32bitpreferred PE32  x86     ILONLY | 32BITREQUIRED | 32BITPREFERRED
#x86 managed       /platform:x86                  PE32  x86     ILONLY | 32BITREQUIRED
#x86 mixed         n/a                            PE32  x86     32BITREQUIRED
#x64 managed       /platform:x64                  PE32+ x64     ILONLY
#x64 mixed         n/a                            PE32+ x64  
#ARM managed       /platform:arm                  PE32  ARM     ILONLY
#ARM mixed         n/a                            PE32  ARM  

    $isILOnly = ($flag32bit -band $COMIMAGE_FLAGS_ILONLY) -eq $COMIMAGE_FLAGS_ILONLY;
    $Obj.Log += 'ILONLY: ' + $isILOnly;
    if ($machineType -eq 0x1c0) {#if ARM
        if ($isILOnly) { $Obj.Result = 'ARM managed'; } 
                  else { $Obj.Result = 'ARM mixed'; }
    }
    elseif ($pe32 -eq 0x10b) {#pe32
        $is32bitRequired = ($flag32bit -band $COMIMAGE_FLAGS_32BITREQUIRED) -eq $COMIMAGE_FLAGS_32BITREQUIRED;
        $is32bitPreffered = ($flag32bit -band $COMIMAGE_FLAGS_32BITPREFERRED) -eq $COMIMAGE_FLAGS_32BITPREFERRED;
        $Obj.Log += '32BIT: ' + $is32bitRequired;    
        $Obj.Log += '32BIT PREFFERED: ' + $is32bitPreffered 
        if     ($is32bitRequired  -and $isILOnly  -and $is32bitPreffered) { $Obj.Result = 'AnyCpu 32bit-preffered'; }
        elseif ($is32bitRequired  -and $isILOnly  -and !$is32bitPreffered){ $Obj.Result = 'x86 managed'; }
        elseif (!$is32bitRequired -and !$isILOnly -and $is32bitPreffered) { $Obj.Result = 'x86 mixed'; }
        elseif ($isILOnly)                                                { $Obj.Result = 'AnyCpu'; }
   }
   elseif ($pe32 -eq 0x20b) {#pe32+
        if ($isILOnly) { $Obj.Result = 'x64 managed'; } 
                  else { $Obj.Result = 'x64 mixed'; }
   }

   $b.Close();   
   if ($showLog) { Write-Host ($Obj.Log | Format-List | Out-String); }
   if ($Obj.Result -eq ''){ return 'Unknown type of file';};
   $flags = '';
   if ($isILOnly) {$flags += 'ILONLY';}
   if ($is32bitRequired) {
        if ($flags -ne '') {$flags += ' | ';}
        $flags += '32BITREQUIRED';
   }
   if ($is32bitPreffered) {
        if ($flags -ne '') {$flags += ' | ';}
        $flags += '32BITPREFERRED';
   }
   if ($flags -ne '') {$flags = ' (' + $flags +')';}
   return $Obj.Result + $flags;
}
```

usage example:

```
#$filePath = "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regedit.exe";#32 bit native on 64bit windows
$filePath = "C:\Windows\regedit.exe";#64 bit native on 64bit windows | should be 32 bit native on 32bit windows

Get-Bitness2 $filePath $true;
```

you can omit second parameter if you don't need to see details

Answer (score 3):

64-bit binaries are stored in PE32+ format. Try reading http://www.masm32.com/board/index.php?action=dlattach;topic=6687.0;id=3486

Answer (score 3):

Open the dll with a hex editor, like [HxD](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/)

If the there is a "dt" on the 9th line it is 64bit.

If there is an "L." on the 9th line it is 32bit.

Comment: Can't find "dt" and "L." on the "Far Manager" HEX viewer.

Comment: Showed as d. and L.

Answer (score 2):

A quick and probably dirty way to do it is described here: https://superuser.com/a/889267. You open the DLL in an editor and check the first characters after the "PE" sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Because of third-party tool always installing in `%Program files (x86)%` (even if x64 installation!) and requiring appropriate x32|x64 fortran runtime to be first listed on the `%path%` to run correctly, I gathered [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9783522/684399) and [powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40739935/684399) solutions into matlab to return:

- **Kind**: `Executable|Library|Other`
- **CodeType**: `Native|Mixed|Managed`
- **Platform**: `x32|x64|AnyCpu|x32Preferred|Other`

It should be easy to adapt to other languages once having raw PE structures in memory.

```
function [simplifiedInfo] = GetPortableExecutableSimplifiedInfo(filename)
%[
    % Checking arguments
    if (nargin <1), error('MATLAB:minrhs', 'Not enough input argments.'); end

    % Initializing simplified info    
    simplifiedInfo.Kind = 'Other';
    simplifiedInfo.CodeType = 'Other';
    simplifiedInfo.Platform = 'Other';

    % Obtaining raw info
    [rawInfo, PEConstants] = GetPortableExecutableRawInfo(filename);

    % Determining 'Kind' of PE
    if (isfield(rawInfo, 'PEOptionalHeader') && (rawInfo.COFFHeader.Characteristics.IMAGE_FILE_EXECUTABLE_IMAGE))
        if (rawInfo.COFFHeader.Characteristics.IMAGE_FILE_DLL)
            simplifiedInfo.Kind = 'Library';
        else
            simplifiedInfo.Kind = 'Executable';
        end
    else
        % No optional header or no IMAGE_FILE_EXECUTABLE_IMAGE flag ... 
        % Maybe just .obj or other thing
        simplifiedInfo.Kind = 'Other';
    end

    % Determining 'CodeType'
    % NB: 'COR20Header' is present for MSIL code, but not for native code
    if (isfield(rawInfo, 'COR20Header'))
        if (rawInfo.COR20Header.Flags.COMIMAGE_FLAGS_ILONLY)
            simplifiedInfo.CodeType = 'Managed';
        else
            simplifiedInfo.CodeType = 'Mixed';
        end
    else
        simplifiedInfo.CodeType = 'Native';
    end

    % Determining platform
    if (rawInfo.COFFHeader.Machine == PEConstants.IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_AMD64)
        simplifiedInfo.Platform = 'x64';
    elseif (rawInfo.COFFHeader.Machine == PEConstants.IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_I386)
        if (isfield(rawInfo, 'COR20Header'))
            % PE contains MSIL code, need more checks
            if (rawInfo.COR20Header.Flags.COMIMAGE_FLAGS_32BITREQUIRED)
                if (rawInfo.COR20Header.Flags.COMIMAGE_FLAGS_32BITPREFERRED)
                    simplifiedInfo.Platform = 'x32Preferred';
                else
                    simplifiedInfo.Platform = 'x32';
                end
            else
                simplifiedInfo.Platform = 'AnyCpu';
            end
        else
            % This is native code so ...
            simplifiedInfo.Platform = 'x32';
        end
    else
        % ARM, ...
        simplifiedInfo.Platform = 'Other';
    end
%]
end
```

Source code for internal `GetPortableExecutableRawInfo` function can be obtained [here](https://gist.github.com/CitizenInsane/079849d25d982239ba13dbbdeec8ce93).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can find it in the header of the portable executable.  The corflags.exe utility is able to show you whether or not it targets x64.  Hopefully this helps you find more information about it.

Comment: Thanks Steven but corflags.exe does not work with native assemblies.

Comment: Windows 10: `>corflags libzmq.dll \n\n ... corflags : error CF008 : The specified file does not have a valid managed header`