# Flash ocx "Class not registered" on Windows 7 x64

Tags: wpf, flash, ocx

I have a WPF app that uses Flash10c.ocx developed on a 32 bit machine.  I didn't have to register the ocx on my dev machine, I just installed the latest flash, added a reference and started coding.  When testing on a 64 bit system I get ye old "Class not registered" which I think mean I need to regsvr the ocx.  Is it Ok to just copy the 32 bit ocx (I'm pretty sure its 32 bit as its located in C:\Windows\System32\Macromed on the dev system) to a 64 bit system and register it?

Update: regsvr32 /i flash10c.ocx errors out with "The module flash10c.ocx las loaded but the call to DllRegisterServer failed with error code 0x80004005"

Update 2: I've given up on this and decided to run Flash on 32 bit systems only.  If anyone has a better answer I'd like to hear it but I'm marking the current suggestion as answered to give due credit for the effort.

Comment: if its windows Vista/ 7 you need to do the registration using elevated command prompt

Comment: what is elevated command prompt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it's not working for you is that your WPF application is running as 64-bit.

A .NET application is able to run as 32-bit or 64-bit; and the CLR is JITing your app to whatever architecture the application is running on - in this case 64-bit.

Except you now want your 64-bit application to load a 32-bit dll. This is not possible. A 64-bit process can only load 64-bit dlls. A 32-bit process can only load 32-bit dlls. No amount of fiddling with COM object registration will change this; it's not a question of missing registry entries.

Adobe Flash only comes as a 32-bit dll. Adobe does not now (and hopefully will never) have a 64-bit version.

In order for your WPF .NET application to load the 32-bit flash dll, it needs to be running as 32-bit process. There is a way, in Visual Studio's build configuration, to force your .NET application to only target `x86`, rather than `Any CPU`.

The choices of CPU targets are:

- Any CPU
- x86
- x64
- Itanium

Flash, for what it's worth, doesn't have an Itanium version, either.

See [StackOverflow: Visual Studio “Any CPU” target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516730/visual-studio-any-cpu-target) for more discussion about target cpus.

Comment: For anyone looking for an answer to this question, this is exactly right.  Change the CPU target to x86 if you need to load Flash.

Comment: Hi, Today i am involved in a project which requires to able to work in windows 7 and above. this application is working in Windows XP. when i  build and debug this application i am getting an exception "Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))    while executing the line   AxShockwaveFlash.EndInit();    I have installed latest shockwave player in my dev machne.  my IDE config mgr: set to Any CPU, Do i need to revive all the references with new dll?  or how to register class?    Help me to resolve this..

Comment: @Pranesh The problem is that your IDE config mgr is set to Any CPU.

Comment: @lan Boyd, i changed the same to x86,   still the same issue persist.  i also checked http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/241493/Class-not-registered-Exception-from-HRESULT-x#answer1

Comment: @lan Boyd, i tried  a simple desktop app to play an swf file, it works in my XP system, but same code not working in my window7(64 bit). class not registered error raises in the line   panel1.Controls.Add(axShockwaveFlash1);   help me to solve this

Comment: @lan Boyd  I solved this error upon installing latest Adobe Flash Player ActiveX  V21.

Answer (score 3):

May be the flash installer is meant to be only for 32 bit OS. Hence it did not install properly on a 64 bit machine. The error means that you will need to manually register the ocx but will it register successfully that's a totally different question.

**Edit 1**: here is [Adobe's statement of support for 64-bit systems](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/000/6b3af6c9.html) (*there is none*) (I assume you are using 64 bit browser on a 64 bit machine)

**Edit 2**: Another [forum message about Flash on 64-bit Window](http://forums.techarena.in/windows-x64-edition/981389.htm)s.

Comment: Thanks Ganesh - I'm actually using the ocx control outside of a browser environment, but I realize from your posts I'll need to compile the app 32 bit.  I also tried to use an elevated command prompt but ran into the same error message I described above.