# 64 bit webpart on SharePoint 2007 32 bit

Tags: dll, web-parts

If I develop a 64 bit webpart DLL does it work with [SharePoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SharePoint) 2007 32 bit?

Comment: What makes your webpart 64 bit?

Answer (score 0):

No can do. You can't load 64-bit DLL in a 32-bit process.

Comment: Nope, you can't force 64-bit dll in a 32-bit process. I would rather focus on ArjanP's question of why is your web-part 64-bit only? Can you install a 32-bit version of it?

Comment: Then you have to build two versions of your web part - one 32-bit and one 64-bit. Even if there was a magic setting that would allow 32-bit SharePoint to load 64-bit webparts, I would assume that it's under the control of the SP admin, not yours.

Answer (score 0):

By default a .NET assembly will target "Any CPU" (see Build > Configuration manager in Visual Studio).

This means that the [Intermediate Language (IL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) code produced will be Just In Time (JIT) compiled into 32bit code when running on a 32 bit OS and 64 bit code when running on a 64 bit OS.

Unless you are doing something very funky (which is unlikely in a SharePoint web part) then you should leave it as "Any CPU" and simply not worry about it any more - it will just automagically work.

- [SO - Visual Studio “Any CPU” target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516730/visual-studio-any-cpu-target)
- [Visual Studio .NET Platform Target Explained](http://visualstudiohacks.com/articles/visual-studio-net-platform-target-explained/)