# How make autoscroll in Scintilla?

Tags: scroll, scintilla

I have a simple VB.NET application using Scintilla. I don`t know how can I make the control auto scroll when text is added to it.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done.

Scintilla can auto-scroll by calling:

`Scintilla1.Scrolling.ScrollBy(0, Scintilla1.Lines.Count)`

so it scrolls to the last text line.

Comment: you can also use SCI_SCROLLCARET without arguments which does the same as above and checks for caret policy as well.

Comment: @RaptorX What function do you call with the SCI_SCROLLCARET option?

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution didn't work for me when trying to make a ScintillaNET editor control scroll to the bottom line after updating the Text property.  Perhaps it's because I am embedding it in a WPF WindowsFormsHost.  In any event, here is the code I used to make the ScintillaNET editor control auto-scroll in my context. (Note, the code is in C#):

```
// Declaration for the WinAPI SendMessage() method.
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint wMsg, UIntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

/// WM_VSCROLL -> 0x0115
public const int WM_VSCROLL = 277;

/// SB_BOTTOM -> 7
public const int SB_BOTTOM = 7;

// scintillaCtl should be a reference to the Scintilla control you want to scroll vertically.
SendMessage(scintillaCtl.Handle, WM_VSCROLL, new UIntPtr(SB_BOTTOM), IntPtr.Zero);
```