# Writing text editor with keywords Highlighting

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, text-editor

I am writing text editor in c# winforms and I want it to Highlight keywords.
Now richtextbox is to slow for opening big files so I am using textbox, but textbox doesn't have a property for setting the color of a selected text.
I tried to inherit from textbox and override OnPaint method but it doesn't seem to work.
I found [this](http://www.codedblog.com/2007/09/17/owner-drawing-a-windowsforms-textbox/) code and it looks great but I have no idea how to work with it.

Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you heard of Scintilla? [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393895/how-to-use-scintilla-net-in-c-project) or [here](http://www.google.com/search?num=100&hl=en&q=Scintilla%20c#%20.net%20syntax%20&btnG=Search)

Answer (score 3):

I'd follow one of the following paths:

1. Go purchase a ready-made text editor component with the desired functionality.
2. Write a custom control from scratch.

The standard controls you mentioned were not designed for such advanced scenarios which require a much more elaborate processing of the content being edited.