# project build targets - mixing x64 and x86 project builds

Tags: visual-studio, build

Shorter version:
Is there a relatively easier way to change the target build for projects in the same solution, short of using some dedicated build tool?

Longer version:
I would prefer to use the x64 version of SQLite; as I understand it there is unmanaged code in it, so you can't build to AnyCpu, although there is an x86 version. Some legacy data in this project comes from an old MS Access system, as I understand that, it can only be run in x86. So I guess I need to either switch to the x86 SQLite version until I can get rid of Access, but maybe someone has a better idea.

Question:
There are 12 projects in this solution so it is a chore to switch the platforms manually. Or am I better off leaving every project as AnyCpu except for the executing ones that use Access?

Cheers,
Berryl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best answer re: AnyCPU option in general is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516730/visual-studio-any-cpu-target)