# C# Project "Any CPU" question

Tags: .net, windows, c#-2.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Visual Studio “Any CPU” target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516730/visual-studio-any-cpu-target)

If I mark my project as "Any CPU" will it *always* run as 64bit executable on a 64bit Windows?

Comment: Previously answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/516730/visual-studio-any-cpu-target