# How to ensure my 64bit box produces 32bit IIS assemblies

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, 32bit-64bit, iis-express

Lately I've run into some unstable behavior with the Web Site Admin pages and I wonder if I've crossed 64bit/32bit lines. I'm working off a Win7 64bit box but only interact with IIS in 32bit mode.

What steps do I take to be sure that, from a Visual Studio / IIS Express / Framework point of view, the 64bit stuff is not used and does not influence anything on my dev machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is set the Target Platform to 32-bit (x86).

Avoid both the "x64" and ["Any CPU"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516730/visual-studio-any-cpu-target) targets.