# Using CreateFile to create a handle for a USB device on 64 bit OS

Tags: c#, .net, usb

I have the following code used to create a valid handle using `CreateFile` working on a 32 bit XP OS. When testing the same code on a 64 bit Vista and Windows 7 computer, `CreateFile` returns an invalid handle value. I can not seem to figure out what is going on.

Here is the dll import:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr CreateFile(
     string FileName,
     uint DesiredAccess,
     uint ShareMode,
     IntPtr SecurityAttributes,
     uint CreationDisposition,
     uint FlagsAndAttributes,
     IntPtr hTemplateFile
     );
```

And the call:

```
drive = CreateFile(devicePath,
           GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
           FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
           IntPtr.Zero,
           OPEN_EXISTING,
           FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE,
           IntPtr.Zero);
```

`devicePath` is a valid path to the usb. This returns a valid handle on a 32 bit OS and an invalid value on a 64 bit OS. I have searched and searched and found nothing. If anyone could help or share some information I would be thankful. 
Regards.

Comment: @pstrjds Compiling for x86 is the opposite of what he should be doing. `CreateFile` returns `HANDLE`, which is `PVOID`, also known as `void*`. On a 64-bit OS, the returned value should be 64-bit.

Comment: @Polynomial - Yeah, I realized that I had inverted my logics after I typed it, which is why I deleted my comment :)

Comment: In the 64 bit OS when you are getting a -1, have you checked what the last error was. Maybe you are running into some UAC permission type issue on your 64 bit OS.

Comment: that seems to be the case, thank you. I get error code 5, access denied

Answer (score 2):

Verify that you're compiling for [AnyCPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516730/visual-studio-any-cpu-target). If you compilation target is x86, you'll have 32-bit `IntPtr` types on both 32-bit and 64-bit operating systems. Compiling for AnyCPU allows the `IntPtr` data type to reflect the size of a pointer.

The `CreateFile` API returns `HANDLE`, which is an alias for `PVOID` (a.k.a. `void*`), so it'll be 64 bits long on a 64-bit OS, and 32 bits long on a 32-bit OS.

When you compile for x86, the code expects a 32-bit value to be returned by the API. Since it's actually 64-bit, you lose half of it, giving you an invalid pointer.

Comment: it does compile in x86 and yields a 32 bit type. on x64 it returns a -1

Comment: @dechiada In Visual Studio, go to Build -> Configuration Manager, and set the Active Solution Platform dropdown at the top to Any CPU.

Comment: Go to Project -> Properties, then look in the Build tab. Under Platform Target, check that it's set to Any CPU.

Comment: It is also set to any CPU there

Comment: Odd. Please verify that `IntPtr.Size` is 8 on the 64-bit system.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth mentioning (since so many people get it wrong) that on 64-bit Windows, handles may safely be truncated to 32 bits.

This allows the handles to be compatible with 32-bit applications (but not 16-bit applications) without special "handle transform" thunking.

Going the other way, truncated 32 bit handles may be safely sign extended to 64 bits. (The invalid handle -1 must by sign extended)

[MSDN "Running 32-bit Applications"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384249%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) "handles have 32 significant bits on 64-bit Windows."