# How to avoid 32/64 bit architecture dilemma in Windows and .Net?

Tags: .net, deployment, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, 32-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the Visual Studio “Any CPU” target mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516730/what-does-the-visual-studio-any-cpu-target-mean)

We have a WPF application that must work on plenty of Windows machines from Windows XP x32 to Windows 8 x64. Our app includes NHibernate and SQLite. We do not need any feature of x64. How can modify application to run without any problem on all architectures?

- Our app is in .Net 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have both the 64bit and 32 bit dll's of your external dependences I would just compile for the lowest common denominator i.e: x86 it will install and run correctly on both 32 bit and 64 bit versions of windows.

Comment: I use sqlite that have 2 editions. One for 32 bit and another for 54 bit

Comment: @afsharm That is well an good, though since you said you do not use anything x64 specific I would probably still compile for x86.

Comment: Yes we do not need any specific x64 feature. We just want our simple app to run in both x32 and x64 environment. I must give a try to x86 compile option.

Answer (score 2):

Compile it for the [AnyCpu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516730/what-does-the-visual-studio-any-cpu-target-mean) architecture, this will make it x86/x64 agnostic.

Of course this won't prevent issues if you are looking to access bitness specific things like %PROGRAMFILES%, if you do this you will still need to test for bitness using the [Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.is64bitoperatingsystem.aspx) property.