# Application with SQLite want run on other Windows

Tags: .net, sqlite

I'm facing with strange problem. My app is developed in .Net 2010 (C#), sqlite 1.0.84.0. Win7 x86. When I transfer app on other computer (Win 7 32 bit) i get this error:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: aprox.minipos.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 51d5f704
  Problem Signature 04: System.Data.SQLite
  Problem Signature 05: 1.0.84.0
  Problem Signature 06: 50edc3cb
  Problem Signature 07: 179
  Problem Signature 08: 1c
  Problem Signature 09: System.ObjectDisposedException
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1050
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

I must mention that all files are copied (System.Data.SQLite.dll, etc, etc...) and also on other computer is installed SQLite 1.0.84.0

Also I have change app.config and add this lines:

```
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite"/>
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

Then I have changed references to 1.0.86.0 and same error occurs. Also in Build options is configured to Any CPU.

I'm tottaly confused... What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the Target Platform to X86 rather than Any CPU. It appears to be an issues with referencing a 32bit/64bit DLL.

All this may have some more information of use: [What does the Visual Studio "Any CPU" target mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516730/what-does-the-visual-studio-any-cpu-target-mean)

Comment: I do that right now and still same error. Few week ago I wrote similar application. It uses almost everything that this new app and it works perfectly on other machines. Also I have compared and all configurations are the same. I really don't know what is wrong... :/

Comment: Hmm ok, sorry I couldn't be more help. In order to narrow down that this is definitely a 32/64bit issue have you tried copying this to another 64bit machine to check its working there?

Comment: I didn't try on 64bit machine except on my. The only strange thing is that my previous project made on same machine with same libraries (i've checked reference paths and other proprties) works fine on 32bit machine but this one doesn't. Almost the same code is used, UI controls... I don't know what else to try...

Comment: Problem solved... I'm so stupid... I have connection string; one for using DB during development and another for production. Of course, me stupido forgot to remove connection string for development and of course wrong path was given. But in the end I learned some new things about other stuffs during investigation couse of this problem :)