# Creating high-performance code for any CPU using C# and C++/CLI

Tags: c#, c++-cli, ipc, cpu-architecture

I'm creating a DirectX application with native C++ and using C++/CLI to facilitate IPC with a C# application.

However, when it comes to building the entire solution; I'm confused about how to make the system work for x86 and x64 CPU architectures, whilst still maintaining as high-performance as possible.

I'm wary of (and want to avoid) any sort of emulation (e.g. WoW32/64).

Of course, I can compile the C# projects using AnyCPU. But then what do I compile the C++ output as?

Do I just compile two separate builds; one for x86 and one for x64?

Thank you

Comment: WoW is not emulation. x86-64 is not emulation. Of course, there still might be a performance degradation or limitation running 32-bit code with 64-bit DirectX drivers. (IA-64 does emulate x86. Perhaps that's why it's not used anymore.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do 2 separate builds.

AnyCPU means that the managed code will execute as 32bit on a 32bit architecture, and 64bit on a 64 one (the JIT takes care of it).
see here: [What does the Visual Studio "Any CPU" target mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516730/what-does-the-visual-studio-any-cpu-target-mean)

But since you have unmanaged code, you'll need to have 2 distincts dlls for the 32bit version and the 64 one of it. So unless you choose the unmanaged dll to load **and the wrapper to use** at runtime by detecting which architecture it is indeed (and I'm not sure you can actually), you'll need to make 2 separate builds.

Comment: To clarify, (as stated in the accepted answer to the linked question) AnyCPU means the assembly can be loaded in a 32-bit or a 64-bit *process*. So on X64 Windows, it can execute as either 32-bit or 64-bit code. When creating a process from an AnyCPU assembly, X64 Windows naturally creates a 64-bit process.

Comment: +1 Yep just done this. Created two unmanaged C++/CLI DLLs and installed into the GAC. The C# project then loads the right one dynamically at runtime