# Determine if program was built with AnyCPU

Tags: windows, visual-studio, 32-bit, anycpu, dumpbin

After reading
[this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/516730#comment29667431_516744)

> If it is built in "any cpu", it will show up as 32bit in dumpbin headers.

I would like to know how I can tell a regular 32-bit program from an
[AnyCPU](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/zekwfyz4) program. I would prefer
to do this from the command line if possible. I tried

```
dumpbin YourProgram.exe /headers
```

on a program of each type, but could not tell them apart in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare these two

```
PS > Start-Process -PassThru chocolatey.exe | Get-Process -Module

   Size(K) ModuleName
   ------- ----------
        40 chocolatey.exe
      1700 ntdll.dll
       444 MSCOREE.DLL
      1148 KERNEL32.dll
       432 KERNELBASE.dll
```

```
PS > Start-Process -PassThru firefox.exe | Get-Process -Module

   Size(K) ModuleName
   ------- ----------
       272 firefox.exe
      1700 ntdll.dll
       252 wow64.dll
       368 wow64win.dll
        32 wow64cpu.dll
```

So if you see `wow64.dll` then it is 32-bit, otherwise the program is 64-bit
capable.