# c# - Windows PowerShell workflow does not work with Process.Start() or PowerShell.Create()

Tags: c#, powershell, console-application, workflow, process.start

I try to run Windows PowerShell workflow script from console application.

Approach 1:

```
var processInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo()
{
            FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe",
            Arguments = $"\"{scriptFile}\"",
            UseShellExecute = false               
};
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(processInfo).WaitForExit();
```

Approach 2 :

```
 RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfiguration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
        using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfiguration))
        {
            runspace.Open();
            RunspaceInvoke runspaceInvoke = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);
            Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
            pipeline.Commands.Add(new Command(scriptFile));
            var psObjects = pipeline.Invoke();
        }
```

The above two approaches give me the error - *Windows PowerShell Workflow is not supported in a Windows PowerShell x86-based console. Open a Windows PowerShell x64-based console, and then try again*

Approach 3:

```
WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo();
connectionInfo.ShellUri = "Microsoft.PowerShell.Workflow";
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);
runspace.Open();
PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();
powershell.AddCommand(scriptFile, true);
powershell.Invoke();
```

Error for Approach 3 - *Connecting to remote server localhost failed with the following error message : Access is denied*.

I am bit hesitant to use *Set-PSSessionConfiguration* as I am not much aware of its after effects. I am running this code on Windows Server 2012.

How can I run the workflow using c# ?

Comment: It seems you are running a version of powershell incompatible with your computer judging by the errors. Maybe try to install an 86 bit version of Powershell core? On the last attempt di you run as admin?

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527513/execute-powershell-script-from-c-sharp-with-commandline-arguments and see if it answers your question

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the question, I was using Console application to run the Windows PowerShell workflow script.

**I changed the app's target platform to 'x64' as the machine has 64-bit OS. It worked.**

Earlier the configuration was **'Any CPU'**

[Any CPU](https://stackoverflow.com/a/516744/5407080) means .NET Framework decides whether to run the program in x64 or x86 bits.
But in this case, I was trying to run a PowerShell script which is not a part of console application. Hence I believe I had to specify the target platform as x64.

I was able to run PowerShell Workflow script successfully using C# on Windows Server 2012 R2 & Windows 10 Enterprise.
Approach 1 & 2(mentioned in question) both worked.