# How can I programmatically tell in C# if an unmanaged lib is x86 or x64?

Tags: c#, c++

How can I programmatically tell in C# if an unmanaged lib is x86 or x64?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480696/how-to-find-if-native-dll-is-compiled-as-x64-or-x86

Answer (score 2):

Unless you get a better solution - run Corflags using `Process.Start` and parse the output.

Or better yet - read the file header from .NET - luckily a this question already been answered: [How to find if native dll is compiled as x64 or x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480696/how-to-find-if-native-dll-is-compiled-as-x64-or-x86)

Comment: So doesn't that make it a duplicate?

Comment: hi Dror,

I Have already gone through the link but it is working for DLL not for libraries.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi All,
I am getting exception on the below line when i am trying to find whether the lib is x86 or x64...

UInt32 peHead = br.ReadUInt32();

Is i need to do some chnages for the library files.