# Interpreting the CorFlags flags

Tags: corflags

How do I interpret the [CorFlags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164699(v=vs.110).aspx) flags and how should I use it to determine if a .NET assembly was built for x86 or x64?

Could it be the following?

```
corflags MyAssembly.dll
```

Comment: A canonical is *[How can I determine if a .NET assembly was built for x86 or x64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270531/)* (contains information about CorFlags, its output, and interpretation), but it hasn't been updated to cover the new flags *32BITREQ* and *32BITPREF* (as this one has).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Open the Visual Studio Command Prompt (in Windows: menu *Start* → *Programs* → *Microsoft Visual Studio* → *Visual Studio Tools* → *Visual Studio 2010 Command Prompt*)

CD to the directory containing the DLL in question.

Run *corflags* like this:

```
corflags MyAssembly.dll
```

The output looks like this:

```
Microsoft (R) .NET Framework CorFlags Conversion Tool.  Version  4.0.30319.1

Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Version   : v4.0.30319
CLR Header: 2.5
PE        : PE32
CorFlags  : 1
ILONLY    : 1
32BIT     : 0
Signed    : 0
```

The flags' interpretation:

```
Any CPU: PE = PE32 and 32BIT = 0

x86: PE = PE32 and 32BIT = 1

64-bit: PE = PE32+ and 32BIT = 0
```

Comment: The answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/23614024/3923734 is more up to date than this one.

Comment: While technically corect for it's time.... the answer below for .NET 4.5 is more accurate/up to date.

Comment: As "Any CPU" compilation, Corflags output is strange for me
PE        : PE32+ | 32BIT     : 0. 
is this Possible ?

Answer (score 115):

Microsoft **.NET 4.5** introduced a new option, **Any CPU 32-bit Preferred**. In the new version of CorFlags.exe, the 32BIT flag no longer exists, instead, two new flags were added, **32BITREQ** and **32BITPREF**.

Somewhere based on the below explanation, we can interpret new CorFlags as follows.

```
CPU Architecture           PE      32BITREQ   32BITPREF
------------------------   -----   --------   ---------
x86 (32-bit)               PE32           1           0
x64 (64-bit)               PE32+          0           0
Any CPU                    PE32           0           0
Any CPU 32-Bit Preferred   PE32           0           1
```

> Flags displayed by the **CorFlags.exe** located at ***C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools***
>
> ```
> Version   : Assembly's target framework.
> Header    : 2.0/2.5 (Must have version of 2.5 or greater to run natively)
> PE        : PE32 (32-bit)/PE32+ (64-bit)
> CorFlags  : Hexadecimal value, computed based on below 4 flags.
> ILONLY    : 1 if MSIL otherwise 0
> 32BITREQ  : 1 if 32-bit x86 only assembly otherwise 0
> 32BITPREF : 1 if 32-bit x86 only preferred in Any CPU architecture otherwise 0
> Signed    : 1 if signed with strong name otherwise 0
> ```

The following example illustrates the output of `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\CorFlags.exe` for different assemblies.

*PresentationCore.dll from **GAC_32***

```
CorFlags.exe "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_32\PresentationCore\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationCore.dll"

Version   : v4.0.30319
CLR Header: 2.5
PE        : PE32
CorFlags  : 0xb
ILONLY    : 1
32BITREQ  : 1
32BITPREF : 0
Signed    : 1
```

*System.Data.dll from **GAC_64***

```
CorFlags.exe "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_64\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll"

Version   : v4.0.30319
CLR Header: 2.5
PE        : PE32+
CorFlags  : 0x18
ILONLY    : 0
32BITREQ  : 0
32BITPREF : 0
Signed    : 1
```

*System.dll from **GAC_MSIL***

```
CorFlags.exe "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll"

Version   : v4.0.30319
CLR Header: 2.5
PE        : PE32
CorFlags  : 0x9
ILONLY    : 1
32BITREQ  : 0
32BITPREF : 0
Signed    : 1
```

To know more about *Any CPU 32-bit Preferred* assemblies refer
[What AnyCPU Really Means As Of .NET 4.5 and Visual Studio 11](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2012/04/04/what-anycpu-really-means-as-of-net-4-5-and-visual-studio-11.aspx)

Answer (score 10):

To add more detail to the other answers, the actual important value is the hexadecimal CorFlags value since it carries the most information. Here's the list of bits that comprise it:

```c#
[Flags]
public enum CorFlags
{
    ILOnly           = 0x00000001,
    Requires32Bit    = 0x00000002,
    ILLibrary        = 0x00000004,
    StrongNameSigned = 0x00000008,
    NativeEntryPoint = 0x00000010,
    TrackDebugData   = 0x00010000,
    Prefers32Bit     = 0x00020000,
}
```

Corflags outputs the four bits of this value separately (ILONLY, 32BITREQ, 32BITPREF and Signed). However the full CorFlags value also contains information about whether the assembly is strong-name signed or delay signed (0x8 bit) as well as ILLibrary, NativeEntryPoint and TrackDebugData bits (I don't know what those mean).

Note that CorFlags output *Signed* is not exactly the StrongNameSigned bit. It will print Signed 1 if the assembly is either delay-signed or fully signed, whereas StrongNameSigned bit is set if the assembly is fully signed only.

Comment: As far as I can tell, `CorFlags.ILLibrary` is set for the Native Images version of assemblies.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use this table:

```
     CPU    | PE    | 32BIT
  ----------|-------|------
  x86       | PE32  |  1   
  Any CPU   | PE32  |  0   
  x64       | PE32+ |  0
```

Comment: Also in *[How to determine if a .NET assembly was built for x86 or x64?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270531/how-to-determine-if-a-net-assembly-was-built-for-x86-or-x64/270545#270545)*