# CorFlags versions for VS 2008, VS 2010, VS 2012, VS 2013

Tags: .net, visual-studio, assemblies, x86-64, corflags

I have installed VS 2008, VS 2010, VS 2012 and VS 2013.

I have found 8 files CorFlags.exe in subfolders in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\

(for example, one of them is C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Bin\CorFlags.exe)

The CorFlags.exe's has different lenght.

Now, I develop .NET 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, and 4.5.1 applications.

I specifically need to know if the assembly is Any-CPU or x86 only, or X64

Which I should be use ?

updated:

All CorFlags.exe paths

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\x64

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\x64

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\x64

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\x64
```

Comment: It is an SDK tool, you have a lot of SDK versions.  And some extra ones, 7.0 did not come along with VS.  A sane choice is always the latest and greatest.  The one in c:\program files\windows kits :)  Run it from the Visual Studio Command Prompt so you don't have to bother picking one.

Answer (score 1):

You should use latest one since it is **backward compatible** so it can be used to determine target platform of all versions of assemblies. I have tested latest CorFlags.exe with several assemblies and it worked like a charm.

> Latest **CorFlags.exe** has new flags **32BITREQ** and **32BITPREF** which replaced **32BIT** Flag, to know more about
>   CorFlags for .NET Framework 4.5.1 checkout my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23614024/2838594).

Just for information I have changed *AnyCPU assembly to x86 assembly* using CorFlags due to some production issues, which did the trick and saved my life. (Modified assembly was unsigned as well as I don't have the source code of respective assembly.)