# 32 bit dll for Azure Active Directory Authentication through C#

Tags: c#, .net, dll, azure-sql-database, azure-active-directory

My requirement is to connect to Windows Azure SQL Database through windows desktop application. Connection should support both SQL Authentication and Active Directory Authentication. For Active Directory Authentication two dlls are required
1. Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll 
2. Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Platform.dll

I have installed nuget package to get these dlls with command as `Install-Package Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory`

As my application is desktop app, we support both 32bit and 64 bit operating systems. To support 32 bit OS, I need 32 bit version of these dlls.

I tried googling and found a set of dlls [here](https://www.opendll.com/index.php?file-download=microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.platform.dll&arch=32bit&version=3.13.30916.1658&dsc=Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Platform#) but pe deconstructor is showing the platform dll as 64 bit.
[image]

**Question ::**
 Is there a cleaner and trustfull (such as nuget) way to get 32 bit version of these dlls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to download the specific 32-bit version for this dll. Actually the Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll is built for any CPU.

We can check it using the [CorFlags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164699(v=vs.110).aspx) conversion tool. And it should like this:

[image]
Then we can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18608785/how-to-interpret-the-corflags-flags/23614024#23614024) fore detail explanation for the result.