# Could anyone faced this or any explanation for this

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, dll, portable-executable

I have built a project and generated DLLs. Corflags O/P is given below

```
PE=PE32 & 32BIT = 0 build as "Any CPU" in "Release Mode"
```

O/P of CorFlags utility is as expected; it should be like this when built as "Release".

```
PE=PE32+ & 32BIT=0 build as "Any CPU" in "Debug Mode"
```

But this one is for x64 not "Any CPU" config build method. What's the deal with Debug?

All the dependent/reference DLLs are compiled as "Any CPU".

Comment: Lookie here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18608785/how-to-interpret-the-corflags-flags

Comment: I aware about the combination of PE & 32 bit for assembly but why its giving result as x64 in debug mode while it was built as "Any CPU" and correct in release; is that something to deal with system config or something else.