# Not able to deploy the code in Microsoft Azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cognitive-services

I have created one web API which takes input audio in Base64. The objective of this WEB API is, it will convert the speech to text. 
So first I converted the base64 string to a .wav file and then passing the file to a method where I have configured Cognitive Services to convert the .wav to text.
Here I have used Azure cognitive services to convert the .wav file to text. but I am not able to build the solution locally neither publish the code into Microsoft Azure.

The error I am getting is "Cognitive Services Speech SDK doesn't support 'Any CPU' ".

I have changed the "ANYCPU" mode to "X64" (My PC is a 64-bit machine). but still, I am getting the same error.

Comment: Please provide a bit more (relevant) information, so there is a [mcve].

Comment: Please define "deploy the code in Microsoft Azure"

Comment: @CSharpRocks  the term deploy here means I am not able to publish the code to Azure.

Comment: Does it run locally? Please clarify if you are publishing from Visual Studio directly or if you have a build set up in Azure Dev Ops. Also, it may be helpful to [verify what architecture your assemblies are built for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18608785/how-to-interpret-the-corflags-flags).

Comment: @Crowcoder no it is not running locally.

Comment: OK, then your question is misleading, you might consider changing it.

Comment: @Crowcoder I ran the command "corflags Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.csharp.dll" and got the below information;

Version   : v4.0.30319
CLR Header: 2.5
PE        : PE32
CorFlags  : 0x9
ILONLY    : 1
32BITREQ  : 0
32BITPREF : 0
Signed    : 1