# Project references contain 32bit or 64bit

Tags: c#, x86-64

I have a project (C# Exe) whose platform target is x86. It contains references of different third party libraries. I am thinking to shift application from x86 to AnyCPU or x64.

Now problem I am facing is that I don't know references libraries are built on x86 or any other. One way is that I check one by one third party libraries and check their platform target (a length process as it contains too 50+ references).

Is their any way to find that dependent libraries are x86 ones or x64 or other.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480696/how-to-find-if-native-dll-is-compiled-as-x64-or-x86 (should work for unmanaged as well)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GetAssemblyName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyname.getassemblyname.aspx) method to retrieve [AssemblyName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyname.aspx) type, where you have [ProcessorArchitecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.processorarchitecture.aspx) property which provides that information.

Comment: Does this enumerate native DLLs loaded into the process (COM interop, p/invoke)?  Those are the ones most likely to not have 64-bit equivalents.

Comment: Don't think so, Native DLL has not any manifest information, which can be recovered by Reflection.