# Windows command to tell whether a .dll file is 32 bit or 64 bit?

Tags: windows, dll, cmd, 32bit-64bit

I'm looking for a command in windows cmd to tell me if a certain dll file is 32 bit or 64 bit

Is there something like this in windows ?

Comment: How can I test a windows dll to determine if it is 32bit or 64bit? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495244/how-can-i-test-a-windows-dll-to-determine-if-it-is-32bit-or-64bit

Comment: Thanks, I checked this  but I needed a windows command not a script.

Comment: `dumpbin` and `cygwin file.exe` are mentioned there also

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find if a native DLL file is compiled as x64 or x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480696/how-to-find-if-a-native-dll-file-is-compiled-as-x64-or-x86)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

[`DUMPBIN`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177429) is included with Visual C++ and can provide this information with the `/HEADERS` switch.

Example output from a 32-bit image:

```
FILE HEADER VALUES
     14C machine (i386)
       6 number of sections
306F7A22 time date stamp Sun Oct 01 22:35:30 1995
       0 file pointer to symbol table
     1D1 number of symbols
      E0 size of optional header
     302 characteristics
            Executable
            32 bit word machine
            Debug information stripped
```

Comment: Thanks you for that, It worked for windows with Visual C++ SDK installed. 
but I'm targeting a machine with no SDK installed.
is there another command ?!

Comment: @becks: There's nothing built-in. You will have to provide an implementation, be it your own or something like `dumpbin`.

Answer (score 6):

If you have installed 7zip :

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" l "my-program.exe" | findstr CPU
```

Comment: Very simple/elegant and seems to work well when I tested with a Microsoft DLL which is different for 32 and 64 bit versions of Office.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the dbghelp library to obtain the image headers. Then you can read the information you need out of the `FileHeader`.

Here's some sample code. Please forgive the rather lame error handling. I just knocked it up quickly to illustrate, and I'm not even remotely fluent in C++.

```c++
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Dbghelp.h>

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool GetImageFileHeaders(wstring fileName, IMAGE_NT_HEADERS &headers)
{
    HANDLE fileHandle = CreateFile(
        fileName.c_str(),
        GENERIC_READ,
        FILE_SHARE_READ,
        nullptr,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        0
    );
    if (fileHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return false;

    HANDLE imageHandle = CreateFileMapping(
        fileHandle,
        nullptr,
        PAGE_READONLY,
        0,
        0,
        nullptr
    );
    if (imageHandle == 0)
    {
        CloseHandle(fileHandle);
        return false;
    }

    void *imagePtr = MapViewOfFile(
        imageHandle,
        FILE_MAP_READ,
        0, 
        0,
        0
    );
    if (imagePtr == nullptr)
    {
        CloseHandle(imageHandle);
        CloseHandle(fileHandle);
        return false;
    }
    
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS headersPtr = ImageNtHeader(imagePtr);
    if (headersPtr == nullptr)
    {
        UnmapViewOfFile(imagePtr);
        CloseHandle(imageHandle);
        CloseHandle(fileHandle);
        return false;
    }

    headers = *headersPtr;

    UnmapViewOfFile(imagePtr);
    CloseHandle(imageHandle);
    CloseHandle(fileHandle);

    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    IMAGE_NT_HEADERS headers;
    if (GetImageFileHeaders(L"C:\\windows\\system32\\user32.dll", headers))
    {
        if (headers.FileHeader.Machine == IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_I386)
            cout << "x86";
        else if (headers.FileHeader.Machine == IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_IA64)
            cout << "IA64";
        else if (headers.FileHeader.Machine == IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_AMD64)
            cout << "x64";
        else
            cout << "Machine not recognised";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

To link this you need to add `dbghelp.lib` to the additional dependencies of your project. To learn more about the details behind this, refer to the MSDN documentation for the various API calls that are used.

Answer (score 1):

The capability you are looking for is available natively on UNIX systems; use the 'file' command. You can use 'file' on Windows systems if you install Cygwin or one of the other UNIX emulators.

Answer (score 0):

https://superuser.com/questions/358434/how-to-check-if-a-binary-is-32-or-64-bit-on-windows/1823683#1823683

Based on answer: https://superuser.com/questions/358434/how-to-check-if-a-binary-is-32-or-64-bit-on-windows/889267#889267

- Language: VBS
- OS: Windows XP+

Implementation: https://github.com/andry81/contools/tree/HEAD/Scripts/Tools/ToolAdaptors/vbs/read_pe_header_bitness.vbs