# Building 64-bit dll in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, microsoft365

I have a 32-bit dll which works on Windows 10. Now I need to build a 64-bit version of it which works on Microsoft 365. The code is written in C#.

For the current 32-bit dll, I do the following to build a dll and then xll.

1. Find the dependencies by typing the following in Command Prompt:
   ***mvn -U process-resources***
2. In Visual Studio 2017, set Application / Build / Debug as in the following and build the solution:

**Application**
[image: Application]

**Build**
[image: Build]

**Debug**
[image: Debug]

3. After a successful build in Step 2, rebuild to create xll with the following Build Events setting:

**Build Events**
[image: BuildEvents]

After the successful rebuild in Step 3, an xll file is created and it can be loaded from Excel 2016 on Windows 10 machines.

Now, I would like to create a 64-bit version of this (xll) that would work on Microsoft 365 machines. I have searched on the web and talked with my colleagues and they say that setting  Platform to "Any CPU" will ensure the generated xll work in both 32-bit / 64-bit Excel. However, when I try to load the generated xll from Microsoft 365 Excel, it fails to be loaded. Would somebody kindly advise how I can make an xll that would work on Microsoft 365?

**Attempt to build targeting x64** (added after jimcilhinney's suggestion)

I tried a build targeting x64. The build and rebuild were successful but either of Excel 2016 on Windows 10 nor 64-bit Excel on Microsoft 365 was not able to load the generated xll. Here's the steps I tried.

1. Find the dependencies by typing the following in Command Prompt (same as above):
   ***mvn -U process-resources***
2. Set target to x64 from Configuration Manager:

**Configuration Manager**
[image: x64ConfigurationManager]

**Application (same as the above Application screenshot)**

**Build**
[image: x64Build]

**Debug**
[image: x64Debug]

3. Same as Step 3 in the above

Comment: "Microsoft 365" is a marketing/brand term for (formerly-known-as) Office-and/or-Windows-as-a-Service (_*ack!*_), it does not refer to any specific builds or editions or versions of Windows. Please clarify what your actual build target is.

Comment: Thanks Dai. I did not realize that. Let me check.

Comment: Excel version information says it is Microsoft Excel for Microsoft 365 MSO (version 2202 build 16.0.14931.20602) 64 bit.

Comment: If you change the target platform to x64, does it work then?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your suggestion. Let me try when I get back.

Comment: Have added the result of changing the target platform to x64.

Comment: @Kyoto Hi, have you successfully created the xll after changing the target platform to x64？

Comment: Hi. Thank you for checking. An xll was successfully built but it was not loadable from Excel 2016 nor Microsoft 365 Excel as added in my original question. I only tried again so let me try again. Will report the outcome.

Comment: I tried again with the target platform x64. The xll was successfully built but, surprisingly, it is 32-bit. I checked this by running a 7-zip command as in [windows-command-to-tell-whether-a-dll-file-is-32-bit-or-64-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14560866/windows-command-to-tell-whether-a-dll-file-is-32-bit-or-64-bit)