# Where are my custom registry key and its values?

Tags: registry, installscript, installshield-2012

I am new to IntallShield and extending a sizeable InstallScript project to add a new custom registry key (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Company\Product\Foo`) and values regarding a feature on first install.

Based on the project's existing code to add other custom registry keys and values, I added a dedicated function with calls to `RegDBCreateKeyEx` and `RegDBSetKeyValueEx` where appropriate...

```
function BOOL RegisterFooFeature(szBar, szBaz)
    string szValue;
    number nType, nSize;
begin
    RegDBSetDefaultRoot(gnProductRegRootKey); // gnProductRegRootKey = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

    //
    // registry subkey
    //
    if (RegDBKeyExist(gszFooFeatureRegSubkey) < 0) then // gszFooFeatureRegSubkey = "SOFTWARE\\Company\\Product\\Foo"
        if (RegDBCreateKeyEx(gszFooFeatureRegSubkey, gszProductRegClass) < 0) then
            My_AddToLog("RegisterFooFeature:  Unable to create registry key " + gszFooFeatureRegSubkey + ".");

            return FALSE;
        else
            My_AddToLog("RegisterFooFeature:  Created registry key " + gszFooFeatureRegSubkey + ".");
        endif;
    else
        My_AddToLog("RegisterFooFeature:  Found existing registry key " + gszFooFeatureRegSubkey + ".");
    endif;

    //
    // registry values
    //
    nType = REGDB_STRING;
    nSize = -1;

    if (RegDBSetKeyValueEx(gszFooFeatureRegSubkey, gszBarRegValueName, nType, szBar, nSize) < 0) then
        My_AddToLog("RegisterFooFeature:  Unable to set registry value \"" + gszFooFeatureRegSubkey + "\\" + gszBarRegValueName + "\" to \"" + szBar + "\".");

        return FALSE;
    else
        My_AddToLog("RegisterFooFeature:  Set registry value \"" + gszFooFeatureRegSubkey + "\\" + gszBarRegValueName + "\" to \"" + szBar + "\".");
    endif;

    if (RegDBSetKeyValueEx(gszFooFeatureRegSubkey, gszBazRegValueName, nType, szBaz, nSize) < 0) then
        My_AddToLog("RegisterFooFeature:  Unable to set registry value \"" + gszFooFeatureRegSubkey + "\\" + gszBazRegValueName + "\" to \"" + szBaz + "\".");

        return FALSE;
    else
        My_AddToLog("RegisterFooFeature:  Set registry value \"" + gszFooFeatureRegSubkey + "\\" + gszBazRegValueName + "\" to \"" + szBaz + "\".");
    endif;

    return TRUE;
end;
```

...and added a call to it in `OnFirstUIBefore`.

I confirmed through my logging that `OnFirstUIBefore` executes on first install like I expect; and my logging indicates that the new custom registry key (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Company\Product\Foo`) and its values are created; but I do not see the new custom key and its values in the registry like I do the existing custom keys and values after first install.

Where is my new custom registry key?

Comment: You may need to look under `SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node` if your installer is 32bit running on a 64-bit OS

Comment: Got it.  I am testing the installer on Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition and confirmed that the installer is 32-bit using [`DUMPBIN`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3899746/1810429).

Comment: @Blorgbeard: Sorry that I did not address my previous comment to you. Your suggestion was spot-on.  An existing function that `OnFirstUIBefore` called just before `RegisterFooFeature` removed `REGDB_OPTION_WOW64_64KEY` and did not restore it before it returned: I was looking for the new key and its values in the 64-bit part of the registry, but they were in the 32-bit part of the registry - under `SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node` as you suspected.

Comment: Cool, glad to hear you sorted it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that before `OnFirstUIBefore` called `RegisterFooFeature` it called a preexisting function that removed `REGDB_OPTION_WOW64_64KEY`...and did not restore it before it returned.

I was looking for the new key and its values in the 64-bit registry hive, but they were in the 32-bit registry hive - under `SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node` - due to the side effect of the preexisting function.