# Can you believe php -m says yes and phpinfo() says no?

Tags: php, installation, tidy

This is my php.ini

```
extension_dir = "ext"
extension=php_tidy.dll

[Tidy]
;tidy.default_config = /usr/local/lib/php/default.tcfg
tidy.clean_output = Off
```

**Can you belive when I type `php -m`, I get tidy in the list but when I check the `phpinfo()` function, there is no mention about tidy ?**

And when I write `$tidy = new tidy;` in a php file, I get this error `Fatal error: Class 'tidy' not found in E:\DEV\WWW\lexique\load.php on line 32`. (The application worked fine under a previous install)

PHP 5.4.15
Apache 2.4

Comment: Yes, i can `belive` that. Is your question answered now?

Comment: Double check if both sides loading the same php.ini

Comment: `php -m` runs the CLI version, whereas your www script certainly uses the Apache module. Different php.ini, or invalid relative path.

Comment: The previous question, before stackoverflow ask me to change it was like "Installing tidy on php". The question is not if you belive it but: I can't deal with this error. Does someone have an idea about what shoult I check not to get a valid installation ?

Comment: `php -i | grep "php.ini"` (or `php -i | findstr /C:"php.ini"` if you're on windows) should show you which php.ini your CLI version uses. `phpinfo()` has the same info somewhere at the top. They are most certainly using different config files.

Comment: LoadModule php5_module "C:/sys/php-5.4.15/php5apache2_4.dll"¶
PHPIniDir "C:/sys/php-5.4.15"¶ This is the path to the php.ini file I'm dealing with.

Comment: php -i says:¶ Configuration File (php.ini) Path => C:\Windows¶ 
Loaded Configuration File => C:\sys\php-5.4.15\php.ini¶ but C:\Windows\php.ini doesn't exists.

Comment: `Loaded Configuration File => C:\sys\php-5.4.15\php.ini` was the important bit from the php -i command. What does `phpinfo()` in your browser tell you?

Comment: Also: Are you sure you're not trying to load an x64 library in an x86 mod_php / apache? Check your logs.

Comment: phpinfo() says the expected C:\sys\php-5.4.15\php.ini

Comment: apache error.log says `AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads`. My system is x64... I'm not sure about apache and php. I'm checking.

Comment: phpinfo() says:¶ Compiler = MSVC9 (Visual C++ 2008)¶ Architecture = **x86** ¶ Apache Version = Apache/2.4.4 ( **Win32** ) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.4.15¶ **Is it ok ?**

Comment: It's only ok if your php_tidy.dll is also x86. (If you don't know how to check: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480696/how-to-find-if-a-native-dll-file-is-compiled-as-x64-or-x86))

Comment: I got php_tidy.dll in the same downloaded file as my php. I don't know how to check if x86 or not.

Comment: If I set `include_path = .;E:/DEV/PHP_off/libs_off`, I can see the change in phpinfo(). But the existing path is `E:/DEV/PHP/libs` and I still have access to my libs. I don't understand.

Comment: If I modify short_open_tag = On/Off in php.ini, I'm sure I'm working the right php.ini. But settings about include_path and tidy have no effects.

Comment: include_path problem was due to Alias in httpd.conf

Comment: Inside php_tidy.dll binary code, ligne 861, I can see: `<assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.VC90.CRT" version="9.0.21022.8" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b"></assemblyIdentity>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved it adding the PHP folder to the PATH and restarting the computer.

Answer (score 0):

CLI and Apache environments use seperate php.ini configs.  As such they separately define the extensions they use.

php_tidy will have to be enabled on both configurations to work.

This depends on your setup however.  I am using a Ubuntu install as an example which typically contains both directories `/etc/php5/apache2` and `/etc/php5/cli`, each containing their own php.ini file.

The extensions themselves however are usually shared, so you shouldn't need to install them twice.

Comment: I know both php.ini places on Windows. Only the one I'm talking about above is loaded.