# Is it possible to use a null-conditional operator to set a Func<> to null?

Tags: c#, lambda, func, throw, null-conditional-operator

Let's imagine the following situation:

```
public class A
{
    private readonly Func<bool> _myFunction;
    ...
    public A(Func<bool> myFunction)
    {
        _myFunction = myFunction ?? throw new ArgumentNullException();
    }
}
```

```
public class B
{
    private bool _myBool;
    public bool MyBool => _myBool;
}
```

```
public class C
{
    A a;
    B b;
    ...
    public void SomeFunction()
    {
        a = new A( () => (bool)b?.MyBool );
    }
}
```

I would like to have the exception correctly raised in `A` constructor since I want `_myFunction` to be set to null if `b` has not been instantiated.

Basically something like:

```
if (b == null) {a = new A(null);} else {a = new A(() => b.MyBool);}
```

I have tried using the null-conditional operator to do so, but I have being unlucky and I just create a reference to a function that returns `null`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you doing this so that when `_myFunction` runs, `b?.MyBool` is not null? Nothing you do in `SomeFunction` can actually ensure that, since `b` can be set to null at a later point.

Comment: @Sweeper I have modified the text to make more clear. I mainly want the exception to be raised in A constructor because b is currently null.

Comment: `b` may be `null` when `a` is created, but it may not be `null` when `a` calls my `_function`...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The shorter version is probably `a = b is null ? new A(null) : new A(() => b.MyBool);`

But it's not correct anyway:
Unless `b` is readonly, it can be modified and set to `null` before a call to the lambda.

```
b = null;
a.CallMyFunction(); // will call the lambda and fail to evaluate b.MyBool
```

A workaround is to use a *local* (and captured) copy of `b` to declare the lambda:

```
var b2 = b;
a = b2 is null ? new A(null) : new A(() => b2.MyBool)
```

But this time it doesn't respect good practice (SOLID principles):
`A` expect a non null function, **it's not his responsibility to raise an exception if the caller can't build one**.

The code should looks like this:

```
a = BuildAFromB(b); // pass a copy of b
// ....

// static to avoid ambiguity between the field b and the argument b
// To avoid this, it's in guidelines to prefix fields name with _
// _a, _b, ...
static A BuildAFromB(B b)
{
    if (b is null)
        throw new ArgumentException();

    return new A(() => b.MyBool);
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for this. Yes I agree that for solid principles I should not test for null inside A function, but probably the short version you proposed is what I was looking for.

Comment: You can undelete your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74561677/939213) so I can award you the bounty. If not it'll just go to waste. And it's not letting me award the bounty to a deleted question. Then post me some comment to remind me.