# Why does the "Create App Packages" dialog have an option for Neutral/AnyCPU?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, desktop-bridge

Why does the "Create App Packages" dialog have an option for Neutral/AnyCPU?

[image]

On Visual Studio 17.3 we could use it. But now it just gives an error of

> There was a mismatch between the processor architecture...

(For more details of the error etc. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74466154/939213).)

So why does the dialog still have this option? ***Is*** there still a way to build for all architectures in one build? If so, how?

(And if there's a different way for publishing for all platforms at the same time instead of publishing for X86, changing in configuration manager to X64 and publishing, changing to ARM... - I'd be happy to hear about it.)

Also, when not all configurations are checked, it shows an extra message "Select all architectures..." as seen here:

[image]

even though that ***always*** fails, because only what is specified in Configuration Manager can work. So why have that as well?

Comment: Are you using a Windows Application Packaging Project to package a WPF app that targets .NET Core/.NET 5+?

Comment: @mm8 Yes. .Net 6.0. The exact steps are listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74466154/939213). I tried this on another computer with VS2022 17.3.2 and everything worked fine , then updated it to 17.5.1 and got this message as I do on my main computer.