# In win32 c++, is there a way to tell if a DLL is 64-bit?

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I test a windows dll to determine if it is 32bit or 64bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495244/how-can-i-test-a-windows-dll-to-determine-if-it-is-32bit-or-64bit)

I'm in win32 c++ code.  I have the path to a DLL on disk and I want to know whether it is 64-bit or 32-bit.  Is there a way to do this?  I can't seem to find any reference on functions that let you peek inside DLLs.

Thanks,
Phil

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495244/how-can-i-test-a-windows-dll-to-determine-if-it-is-32bit-or-64bit

Answer (score 0):

If this dll is in one of the known folders: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378457%28VS.85%29.aspx), you could decide it easily.

+1 for your first comment.