# What else beyond the VC++ 2005 redistributable is required for deployment?

Tags: visual-c++, deployment, visual-studio-2005

I recently had a hard disk fail on me. I've re-installed Win XP from scratch, updated to SP3, and run the same vcredist_x86.exe that I have always run before to install Visual C++ components. It seems to install... but none of my executables requiring the essential VC++ DLLs will run - they all give the "application configuration is incorrect" message familiar to many of us.

If I run Dependency Walker, I can see that all executables built using VC++ 2005 are simply failing to pick up the likes of MFC80.dll, MSVCRP80.dll, MSVCP80.dll, etc. When I look in the Windows\WinSxS folder, there appear to be folders containing those files in the correct places. These executables ran fine a couple of weeks ago, so I know their manifests are OK.

What could be causing all these applications to fail to run?

Comment: Finally worked out what was happening, so will answer my own question...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the correct up-to-date version of the redistributable is used and/or matches the versions used to build the executable(s). Note also that the version number of the vcredist_x86.exe file will not be the same as the version(s) of the files installed in the WinSxS folder. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8913543/why-installing-vcredist-x86-exe-doesnt-fix-sidebyside-error-when-i-develop-an-e) was really useful for shining light on the version issues.