# VC C++ 2008 redistributable error

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2008, manifest

Okay so I have read a few responses about this topic and can't seem to find someone having the same issue.

[Why installing vcredist_x86.exe doesn't fix SideBySide error when I develop an EXE on one machine and run it on another one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8913543/why-installing-vcredist-x86-exe-doesnt-fix-sidebyside-error-when-i-develop-an-e)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43681/Side-by-Side-Configuration-Incorrect

background: I work on Fortran code that use a few c++ libs that I don't have access to the code of. These were apparently built using VS2008, and this error has only started to occur since my machine had to be rebooted and I asked IT not to install VS2008 in addition to VS2012. I know that installing VS2008 will fix the problem, but that is not a good soultion.

The error is: unable to start program 'C:\blah\blah\blah.exe'. This application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect. Review the manifest file for possible errors. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem. For more details, please see the application event log. The application event log tells me the same things listed in the first link posted.

Originally I was getting the problem so I looked up these articles and I went and installed the correct version of the VC C++ redist package (it is version 9.0.21022.8 for x86 source:the manifest file for the project). I originally installed the 64 bit, quickly determined I needed the 32 bit version and then installed that one.

I have the folders and files within for

- C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.mfc_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_b59bae9d65014b98
- C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.mfcloc_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_b59bae9d65014b98
- C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.atl_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_b59bae9d65014b98

The related manifest files also seem to be there.

The program still doesn't run even though the files are there. What am I missing?

Comment: Very first thought is, have you built for the RELEASE version and not the DEBUG version?  The redistributables only contain the RELEASE versions.  Secondly, have you examined the manifest in the executable/dll and verified that the versions it is asking for you have on your computer?

Comment: No, I have not built in release version... I didn't know it was only for that. Is there any way to continue running my program in debug mode, so I can keep developing without installing VS2008 since I don't need to debug those libraries affected?

I have not found a manifest for the '*.lib' files.

Comment: Well, if the application event log entry is an exact match then it told you that you installed the wrong version, VC80 is not VC90.  VC80 is the VS2005 runtime.  Don't let code run wild, if you have a dependency on a C++ library then you'd better have a phone number.

Comment: I meant that it was the equivalent error message for the version I was having an issue with... None of this was my choice. The other people's code (these libraries) have been an issue for me since I started.

Comment: You will need to either build the Release version, or install Visual Studio.  You can build for Release that is almost like Debug.  Turn off optimizations and then make sure you generate .PDB files for your executable.  Using those settings, you should be able to debug your executable.

Comment: Alright. Thank you. At least now I know. Building in release mode causes those libs to have a whole host of errors because they have conflicting code. Thank you. If you form your comments into a answer I'll accept it as it was the answer to my problem.