# side-by-side configuration incorrect

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

A 32 bit process built on VS2013 in debug configuration has stopped working with message: "the application has failed to start because it's side by side configuration is incorrect". Previous versions of the app, that resided in different folders, also stopped working with same message. Release builds do work. Other apps in debug configuration do work. No OS updates have occurred.

This is output of depends32:
[image]

As can be seen there are 64-dependencies but I'm not familiar with them.

This is partial output of sxstrace.exe:

```
INFO: Resolving reference Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.6195".
INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture WOW64.
    INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral.
        INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
            INFO: No publisher policy found.
            INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
        INFO: Begin assembly probing.
            INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
            INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT\8.0.50727.6195__1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT.DLL.
            INFO: Did not find manifest for culture Neutral.
        INFO: End assembly probing.
INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture x86.
    INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral.
        INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
            INFO: No publisher policy found.
            INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
        INFO: Begin assembly probing.
            INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
            INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT\8.0.50727.6195__1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT.DLL.
            INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at <path>\Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT.DLL.
            INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at <path>\Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT.MANIFEST.
            INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at <path>\Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT\Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT.DLL.
            INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at <path>\Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT\Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT.MANIFEST.
            INFO: Did not find manifest for culture Neutral.
        INFO: End assembly probing.
ERROR: Cannot resolve reference Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.6195".
ERROR: Activation Context generation failed.
```

This is screenshot of VC redistributables installed on machine:

[image]

Building from clean & machine restart didn't help.

How can this be further debugged?

Comment: the x86 debug runtime is missing.

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT **Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT** this is 2005 debug runtime

Answer (score 0):

According to your description,it seems that your debug version of app is linking to the debug version of CRT 2005 without SP1. The debug version of CRT 2005 is only available on machines installed with Visual Studio 2005. If you ran the debug application on a machine without Visual Studio 2005, the error you saw is expected.

I suggest you should install [the VS2005 SP1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=26347)

For more details, I suggest you could refer to the links:
[Why installing vcredist_x86.exe doesn't fix SideBySide error when I develop an EXE on one machine and run it on another one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8913543/why-installing-vcredist-x86-exe-doesnt-fix-sidebyside-error-when-i-develop-an-e)
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1943e726-40e1-49aa-9e1b-23c966bce921/side-by-side-loading-error-when-running-in-debug-mode-in-vs2005-or-deployed-to-progam-files?forum=vcgeneral