# WAMP shows error 'MSVCR100.dll' is missing when install

Tags: wamp, wampserver, msvcr100.dll

When I tried to install **WAMP**, that popped up the following alert,
[image: MSVCR100.dll is missing]

I clicked **OK**, it continued to install WAMP. When I start, the WAMP logo is always 'yellow'. It isn't turning 'green', meaning there's something wrong. What exactly is the `MSVCR100.dll` file? How do I obtain it and fix this error?

Answer (score 267, accepted):

The `MSVCR100.dll` file is part of the `Microsoft Visual C++`, redistributables. You can install them and see if this solves your problem. After you install the above check if your wamp installation is correctly setup. Search for "my wamp icon stays orange" posts.

**UPDATE 2019**

> Wampserver 3 requires Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4
>   You can download it at:
>   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679
>   There you can select the x86 or x64 version depending on your system

[This article](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,123608) on the WampServer forums shows all the Microsoft Visual C++ runtime libraries you need to have installed on your system for each version of WampServer. To quote:

> For Windows 32 : Be sure that you have installed the Visual C++ 2010
>   SP1 Redistributable Package x86  : VC10 SP1 vcredist_x86.exe
>
> http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8328
>
> For Windows 64 : Be sure that you have installed the Visual C++ 2010
>   SP1 Redistributable Package x64  : VC10 SP1 vcredist_x64.exe
>
> http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13523
>
> Apache will not run without this component
>
> In fact if you are running the 64bit Windows it is a good idea to install all the 32bit libraries as well as the 64bit ones. After all 64bit windows runs 64 and 32 bit code. You will probably find you need at least one of the 32bit runtimes for some app/utility you will install at some point.

**UPDATE**

If you are running WAMPServer 2.5 you also need the VC11 redist. Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012

29.08.2014 with WAMP 2.5
I agree that VC11 is needed and it is not a bad idea to have previous distributions installed. It will be needed by other application. I am not sure if you need bit 32 version

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=30679

**UPDATE** Aug. 3rd 2016

As I was informed by Fred -ii- (many thanks by the way) the link for the post in the wamp forums doesn't work anymore. Since I could not find the original link you can try http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,138295. It has lots of info and may help you.

Comment: wamp 2.2 is funny this way: i'm using win64, but the vcredist 64b is not enough, i had to install both vcredist 32b and 64b. just a note for someone who may get stuck like me

Comment: Visual C++ 2010 itself is not enough, I installed it but still the problem was not resolved. You also need to install Visual C++ 2008 http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/confirmation.aspx?id=29 as wamp uses some of the libraries from VC++ 2008. I know it's a bit weird but mine problem was solved when I installed VC++ 2008 and also the wamp forum states the same for this problem.

Comment: And make sure you reboot after installing the Redistributable.. otherwise Wamp won't see it. At least it didn't in my case.

Comment: FYI - I installed both 32 and 64 and the 2008 still not working.

Comment: It's kind of mentioned above but for clarity... if you're getting an error message about MSVCR110.dll (and not MSVC100.dll) you'll need the Visual C++ 2012 redistributable.

Comment: visual c++ 2012 redistributable here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679

Comment: installing visual c++ 2012 redistributable here: microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679 solved my problem. thank you.

Comment: Didn't work for me after installing the first two, but worked after installing the file linked in the update.

Comment: not working .. i install the dll package but not running

Comment: I downloaded both the 32 & 64 bit. You have to install both versions. Restart computer, then reinstall Wamp

Comment: I needed to install the 32bit as well. And now WAMP 3 works for me

Comment: As of Dec 2018 this helped me perfectly: http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,138295

I've download and installed all (86 and 64) redistributables.

Comment: Thank you -- working on a fresh install, July 2020. Different stuff required to install. Install everything! :D

Answer (score 65):

For me none of the above answers worked so I am adding what worked for me. I first installed the files mentioned in the accepted answer and when that not worked, I downloaded files from [this](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679) link and it started working.

So I think 2012 distribution is also needed (I am using window7 home basic 64 FYI).

Comment: Just for anyone looking now, I installed the one in this answer, and wamp finally works! I've done all the other 2008,2010 ones and the other couple of 2012 ones in this post, but this one finally did it!

Comment: Worked for Windows 10 too. :)

Comment: It's still valid in 2020 

Answer (score 13):

I solved this problem by installing this one : http://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/download/details.aspx?id=30679

Be sure to remove wampserver and reinstall it again

Note: I'm using Windows 7 32 bits

Comment: I have ver 3.0.6 64-bit on wins 10, after installing the missing dlls, the icon was orange, left and right clicks didn't work. After **uninstalling** wampserver and install it again, it works.

Comment: thanks for mentioning that I HAVE TO UNINSTALL/REINSTALL IT AFTER INSTALLING VC11 DLL files.

Comment: This worked. And just bringing down the services and starting the WAMP again did the trick for me. No reinstall required in my case.

Answer (score 10):

Most of the time you will have to install **both** x86 and x64 !

**Links here:** [x86](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8328) and [x64](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13523)

They are the  *Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package*

(it happened to me when installing MySQL Workbench)

Answer (score 8):

I have tried all the above answers but still the same error was throwing up.
Later I found this in WAMP Forum and finally my WAMP works !!!

If you are using WampServer 2.5 on a 64bit Windows
You will need both the 32bit and 64bit versions of this runtime.

Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 [(www.microsoft.com)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30679)

Press the Download button and on the following screen select VSU_4\vcredist_x86.exe
Press the Download button and on the following screen select VSU_4\vcredist_x64.exe

Source : http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,123608

Answer (score 6):

Today I installed Wamp server 3.0.6 (x64) on a Windows 10 machine with VS2017 installed. I had many Visual C++ Redistributable Packages installed, but not the 2012 one. Then I installed it and now I can run the Wamp server. You can find a download link [here](https://www.howisolve.com/msvcr110-dll-is-missing/).

Comment: Yes the 2012 version worked for me, current fully updated windows 10 machine and newest wampserver. The direct download link for 64bit: http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/6/B/16B06F60-3B20-4FF2-B699-5E9B7962F9AE/VSU3/vcredist_x64.exe

Comment: lots of the links are now outdated except for this answer. solves my problem.

Answer (score 5):

Just ran on this issue. 
Issue was at same OS (Win7 HB x64) as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23845445/3472757). I used gaurav's advice and successfully started WAMP.

I wanted to add that **you don't need** Visual C++ 2010 versions when using 2012 version (at least in this case).

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem but none of the answer above worked. Here's what did the job for me:

1. download `msvcr110.dll`, `msvcr120.dll`, `msvcp120.dll` and `vcruntime140.dll` from dll-files.com
2. Copy them into System32
3. Uninstall wamp
4. Reinstall wamp

Answer (score 3):

Edit: Since I have encountered the same issue again, I have noticed that my previous solution did not work; as well as any other solution posted here.  I am using Windows 7 Professional (64 Bit).

This time, I have placed the 'MSVCR100.dll'file (downloaded as a ZIP, then extracted onto Desktop and then copied) into a C:\Windows folder http://www.dll-files.com/dllindex/dll-files.shtml?msvcr110

and then installer WAMP Server, 64BIT.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/

Then, I have downloaded and installed:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=30679

filename: vcredist_x64.exe

**I have only tested it with the PHP from a command-prompt**, since I do everything else on a server and not a local-host.

Although it works for what I need to use it

Running:

> php
>   gives Failed loading php_xdebug-2.2.5-5.5-vc11.dll
>
> php -v
>   -WORKS!

Please let me know if this worked for you or not or if there is something else I need to do to improve the fix.

Answer (score 3):

I have installed the new WAMP 2.5, i have **windows 8 x64** bit. 
I have tried All the above solutions but it didn't work with me and the WAMP icon stays **Orange**. the thing that works with me is:

1. uninstall the current WAMP x64 bit
2. install this
   http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679
3. Download and install the WAMP server for x32 bit.
4. Chose Firfox as the browser.

I hope that i will help somebody searching for this answer

Comment: thanks bro, it helped a lot. I have installed everything also, but still doesn't worked until uninstall and installing wamp again

Answer (score 3):

This tool will check for missing packages and also give you download link for packages. .
**If you are on windows 64 bit then you need to install both x86 and x64 packages**
link to download the tool:

[DOWNLOAD](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/files/tools/check_vcredist.exe)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't understand anything then download vcredist_x86.exe from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8328 . It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

After downloading all the libraries said by ezaoutis, the error message on my **windows 10** persisted, reading the **wampserver3.1.3** installation requirements, there  was a verification tool called **check_vcredist.exe** , i ran it and it show me all the missing libraries and it's download links, so i finally could install it succesfully.

[image: Below image with check tool marked]

Answer (score 1):

Re/installing .NET framework did not worked for me. Some less professional soft wares like tuneup utilities manipulate or constantly keep in use .NET framework files. like that .dll . I learned it while i was trying to uninstall .NET updates before re-installation.

- Dont forget to uninstall wamp from control panel before reinstalling it.
- Uninstalling .NET updates of windows. (controlPanel->uninstall a
- program->view updates) Uninstalling soft wares that prevents
- uninstalling .NETs . Finished successfully uninstalling .NET
- framework updates. Check windows updates. Install updates that shows
  up AFTER check (.NET framework update. 3update for me under
  win7x64)
- install wamp (finished flawlessly for me)

Comment: Could you explain "Uninstalling softwares that prevents?"

Answer (score 1):

Step 1. Uninstall WAMP

Step 2. Install the latest [Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Update 3](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=53840)

Step 3. **Restart System**

Step 4. Re-install WAMP

Make sure Skype is not signed in. *You don't want to know details if you are a newbie :)*

Answer (score 1):

For me problem did not resolve even after installing VC++ re-distributions. I had to manually download MSVCR110.dll file from https://www.dll-files.com/msvcr110.dll.html and placed it in c:/ > windows > system32 and it worked correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Went quite easy. I only needed to install these 2 versions in this order:

[Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ie/download/details.aspx?id=40784)

[Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145)

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue you have to install all Microsoft redistribution packages 2010,2012(x86 and x64) than uninstall wampserver from control panel and reinstall new copy of wamp server this error will be get fixed

Answer (score 0):

Installing just `vcredist_x64.exe` from `Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012` fixed the issue for me.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679

I'm using Windows 7 Home Basic 64 bit and installed WampServer 2.5

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem when my operating system was in French, and I was installing Wampserver in English.

I am pretty sure that Microsoft Redistributable packages were installed since I was already working with Visual Studio. I think the issue may have been because of changes in path names with different languages. However, when I installed wampserver in French, everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Some times you have to install all versions or a bunch of them.

Anyone who has not found above answers useful , take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51417613/4799599)

Answer (score 0):

When installing Wamperserver 3 on windows 10, it now gives a nice big warning during the install telling you it won't work unless you install many of these packages.

It worked for me after I followed the instructions and then restart the computer and reinstalled.

> --- Installation of Wampserver --- BEFORE proceeding with the installation of Wampserver, you must ensure that certain elements are
>   installed on your system, otherwise Wampserver will absolutely not
>   run, and in addition, the installation will be faulty and you need to
>   remove Wampserver BEFORE installing the elements that were missing.
>   Make sure you are "up to date" in the redistributable packages VC9,
>   VC10, VC11, VC13 ,  VC14 and VC15 See --- Visual C++ Packages below.
>
> --- Do not install Wampserver OVER an existing version, follow the advice:
>   - Install a new version of Wampserver: http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,123606 If you install
>   Wampserver over an existing version, not only it will not work, but
>   you risk losing your existing databases.
>
> --- Install Wampserver in a folder at the root of a disk, for example C:\wamp or D:\wamp. Take an installation path that does not include
>   spaces or diacritics; Therefore, no installation in c: \ Program
>   Files\ or C: \ Program Files (x86\ We must BEFORE installing, disable
>   or close some applications:
>   - Close Skype or force not to use port 80 Item No. 04 of the Wampserver TROUBLESHOOTING
>   TIPS:http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,134915
>   - Disable IIS Item No. 08 of the Wampserver TROUBLESHOOTING TIPS:http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,134915 If these
>   prerequisites are not in place, Press the Cancel button to cancel the
>   installation, then apply the prerequisites and restart the
>   installation. This program requires Administrator privileges to
>   function properly. It will be launched with the "Run as administrator"
>   option. If you do not want a program to have this option, cancel the
>   installation.
>
> --- Visual C++ Packages --- The MSVC runtime libraries VC9, VC10, VC11 are required for Wampserver 2.4, 2.5 and 3.0, even if you use only
>   Apache and PHP versions with VC11. Runtimes VC13, VC14 is required for
>   PHP 7 and Apache 2.4.17 or more
>
> -- VC9 Packages (Visual C++ 2008 SP1) http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5582
>   http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2092
>
> -- VC10 Packages (Visual C++ 2010 SP1) http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8328
>   http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13523
>
> -- VC11 Packages (Visual C++ 2012 Update 4) The two files VSU4\vcredist_x86.exe and VSU4\vcredist_x64.exe to be download are on
>   the same page:
>   http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679
>   -- VC13 Packages Update 5(Visual C++ 2013) The two files VSU4\vcredist_x86.exe and VSU4\vcredist_x64.exe to be download are on
>   the same page: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4032938/
>
> -- VC14 Packages (Visual C++ 2015 Update 3) Supersedes by VC15
>   - VC15 Redistribuable (Visual C++ 2017) https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/VC_redist.x86.exe 
>   https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/VC_redist.x64.exe VC2017 (VC15) is
>   backward compatible to VC2015 (VC14). That means, a VC14 module can be
>   used inside a VC15 binary. Because this compatibility the version
>   number of the Redistributable is 14.1x.xx and after you install the
>   Redistributable VC2017, VC2015 is removed but you can still use VC14.
>
> If you have a 64-bit Windows, you must install both 32 and 64bit
>   versions of each VisualC++ package, even if you do not use Wampserver
>   64 bit To verify that all VC ++ packages are installed and with the
>   latest versions, you can use the tool:
>   http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/files/tools/check_vcredist.exe and
>   you will find all the packages on http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/ in
>   section Visual C++ Redistribuable Packages You must install each
>   package "as an administrator", so right-click the exe file and then
>   run as Administrator. Do not use a previously loaded tool. Make a new
>   download to make sure you are using the correct version.
>
> Warning: Sometimes Microsoft may update the VC ++ package by breaking
>   the download links and without redirect to the new. If the case
>   happens to you, remember that item number 20 below will be updated and
>   the page http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/ section Visual C++
>   Redistribuable Packages is up to date. This is item number 20 of
>   TROUBLESHOOTING TIPS of Wampserver: 
>   http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,134915

Answer (score 0):

Visual C++ 2013 Update 5 Redistributable Package fixed issue for me. Download link:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3179560/update-for-visual-c-2013-and-visual-c-redistributable-package

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstall WAMP
2. Download  Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual
   Studio 2012 Update 4 and Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for
   Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019

   [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679)

   [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019
   x86](https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vc_redist.x86.exe)

   [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019 x64](https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vc_redist.x64.exe)

- *Note :- Download both x86 and x64 versions if you are using 64 bit O/S*

3. Install both x86 and x64 versions of Visual C++ Redistributable
   Packages for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4 and Visual C++
   Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019

[image]

4. Intsall WAMP again. That's it. All the problems will solve.