# Wamp Server not goes to green color

Tags: php, windows-7, wamp, wampserver, msvcr100.dll

I Installed WAMP Server Successfully.

My OS is: `Windows 7 32-bits`

My Wamp Server is: `2.2E ( 32bits & php 5.3 )`

I had same problem 4 months back. That time, I used [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14557245/wamp-shows-error-msvcr100-dll-is-missing-when-install). (but OS & WAMP are 64-bits) It's worked fine.

Now, that `MSVCR100.dll` not gave any problem. But WAMP logo is always 'yellow' color only. That's not return to 'green'. I installed [vcredist_x86.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8328)

I uninstalled '`Avast`', for my friend refer. But no Use. Help Me...

Thank you...

Comment: may be, when you start skype before wamp, WAMP server will not go green.

Comment: I Quit Skype before run my WAMP. But no use.

Comment: check whether there is IIS or any other application using the WAMPserver's(apache) port.

Comment: Sorry, No one is here. Now only i put my OS.

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/unblock-port-80-on-windows-run-apache/

Comment: I'm having this issue for a long time now but it works when I close Skype. Later I can start Skype again but if Skype started first, WAMP doesn't work. I don't know why that happens but there's probably something wrong with ports they both use. That was mentioned in first comment, and I know a lot of people have same issue with Skype.

Comment: http://theandystratton.com/2012/wampapache-broken-from-microsoft-httpapi-2-0-using-port-80

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can check if the port is being used by other program using WAMP menu -

1. Click on WAMP icon `select Apache -> Service -> Test Port 80`, this will check if the port is used by any other program
2. Also do this `select Apache -> Service -> Install Service`, this will make apache use port 80 if the port is not already used by any other program like IIS or Skype

Restart the WAMP see if the problem is fixed.

If port 80 is already used by some program, then you can choose other listening port for WAMP. To do this -

`click WAMP icon -> Apache -> httpd.conf`

Now find `listen 80` (where 80 is port number, it can be different on your system)

Now change that to something else like 3333, you can access WAMP homepage by typing `localhost:3333` or `127.0.0.1:3333` in browser's address bar.

If you want WAMP to use port 80, uninstall the program that is using port 80 and then do things stated in step 2 or you can change port in that program's setting, also check `httpd.conf` file for `listen [port]` line.

Comment: Can not find listen 80... what to do?

Comment: http://theandystratton.com/2012/wampapache-broken-from-microsoft-httpapi-2-0-using-port-80

Answer (score 7):

I found something I did wrong, install the Apache and MySQL services. Click on the WAMP logo, goto Apache -> Service -> Install Service, after that Apache -> Service -> Start/Resume Service. Do the same for MySQL and it will turn green.

Comment: This fixed my problem, possibly because I installed the latest C++ Redistributable AFTER installing wamp

Answer (score 6):

I would prefer using the most easiest method.

Right click on the Wamp icon and go to

**Tools > Use a port other than 8080 >**

Set a different port, lets say 8081 and that's it. Problem resolved.

*You are most welcome.*

Comment: Worked like a charm

Answer (score 2):

Click wamp icon :

1- apache -> httpd.conf (A notepad file will be opened)

2- Find 80

3 -Replace with 81

> Listen 12.34.56.78:81 Listen 0.0.0.0:81 Listen [::0]:81

4- Restart wamp services

!!Done

Answer (score 2):

I have same issue with IIS, i uninstalled IIS.
Type in run services.msc, I see "wampapache64" service was not running, when I start it using right click it give me error.

I just used these steps.

1. Click on WAMP icon select Apache -> Service -> Remove Service
2. Click on Wamp icon select Apache -> Service -> Install Service

Got green Wamp icon :(

Answer (score 1):

CMD > `netstat -ao` > look for any line like `0.0.0.0:80` and look at the PID value (*e.g. 4796*)

Open Task Manager > Processes tab > View > Select Column > Tick on **PID (Process Identifier)** > OK to create new column

Look at the processes list in Task Manager > Sort by PID (the new column) and find the ***4796*** to know which program is using Port 80. Mine is Bit-Torrent. After close (exit) Bit-Torrent, Wampserver should work as usual.

Answer (score 0):

You should also make sure that the ports WAMP uses aren't already in use.

That can be done by typing the following command into the command prompt:

```
netstat –o
```

Comment: To check what ports are being used you could type the following command "netstat –o" into command prompt, This will output a list of ports, along with the PID (process ID) that has that port open

Answer (score 0):

Open **cmd** and type the command below.

```
netstat -o -n -a | findstr 0.0:80
```

Last column of each row is the process identifier (PID)

You can find the application that reserves port 80, using taskmanager services tab or just type `tasklist` in **cmd**.

Then follow this link: 
http://www.ttkalec.com/blog/resolving-yellow-wamp-server-status-freeing-up-port-80-for-apache/

Answer (score 0):

Quit skype and right click on wamp icon-apache-services-start all services that will work after wamp server is start you can use skype again ;)

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are very reasonable but my solution was simply to run the installer as administrator.

This is clearly stated [here](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,134915) on the wampserver forum (2nd tip).

There are 20 other suggestions as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the above solutions work for me on many occasions, except one; that was after I buggered up an alias file - ie a file that allows the website folder to be located in another location other than the www folder. Here's the solution:

1. Go to c:/wamp/alias
2. Cut all of the alias files and paste in a temp folder somewhere
3. Restart all WAMP services
4. If the WAMP icon goes green, then add each alias file back to the alias folder one by one, restart WAMP, and when WAMP doesn't start, you know that alias file has some bad data in it. So, fix that file or delete it. Your choice.

Answer (score 0):

In the tray, right click on the `wamp icon` select `tools`, in the mysql section, select `use a port other than 3306` you should see a pop up, enter the port number, 3308 will be suggested, the server should restart after you click `Okay`, if not restart it yourself.

That worked for me.

Regards