# WampServer: php-win.exe The program can't start because MSVCR110.dll is missing

Tags: dll, installation, wamp, msvcr100.dll

if I try to install WampServer the above error appears. I already tried to install all the programs which were recommended, for example here:
[WAMP shows error 'MSVCR100.dll' is missing when install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14557245/wamp-shows-error-msvcr100-dll-is-missing-when-install)

But nothing helps. What can I do to install WampServer?

Comment: [Possible Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14557245/wamp-shows-error-msvcr100-dll-is-missing-when-install)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What solves my problem:
I am using 64 bit Windows 7, so I thought I could install 64 bit Wamp. After I Installed the 32-bit version the error does not appear. So something in the developing process at Wamp went wrong...

Comment: Had a similar problem. By mistake, I installed the x86 WAMP version on a x64 Windows. I had to install Visual Studio 2012 VC 11 **x64** version ( vcredist_86.exe ) to make it work. It didn't work with vcredist x64 version, as expected.

Answer (score 30):

During the download of wamp server from wampserver website you get a warning..

> WARNING : Vous devez avoir installé Visual Studio 2012 : VC 11
>   vcredist_x64/86.exe Visual Studio 2012 VC 11 vcredist_x64/86.exe :
>   http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679

So if you install the *vcredist_xxx.exe* it will be ok

Comment: No, I didn't get a warning

Comment: That warning isn't in english and I did not get that warning either

Comment: Your answer is not a workaround, it's a complete fix of the problem. That should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This worked for me. I downloaded so many C++ MS packages (which I saw as recommended solutions to the problem) and they didn't work, and also the 32 bit and 64 bit MSVCR110.dll files from dllfiles.com. None worked. The WAMP set up seems like a lazy, sloppy put-together-job, considering the persistent error messages, that French error message that comes up for english language install etc...

Comment: The message is on the main page, where you can download WAMP Server. My x64 missed the x64 package of this specific version.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I am aware, the `MSVCRxxx.dlls` are in `%SystemRoot%\System32` (usually `C:\Windows\System32`).

**The xxx refers to the version of the `MS Visual C Runtime` (hence MSVCR...)**

However, the complication seems to be that the xxx version is not the same as the two digits of the year "version".

For example,  **Visual C Runtime 2013** yields `MSVCR120.dll` and "...**Runtime 2012**" yields `MSVCR110.dll`.  And *then* Microsoft packages these as `vcredist_x86.exe` or `vcredist_x64.exe`, seemingly irrespective of the xxx version or the Visual Studio version number (2012, 2013 etc) - confused? You have every right to be!

So, firstly, you need to determine whether you need `32 bit`, `64 bit` or even both (some PHP distributions apparently do need both), then download the relevant vcredist... for the bits AND for the Visual Studio version.  As far as I can tell, the only way to tell which vcredist... you have is to start to install it.  Recent versions give an intro screen that quotes the Visual Studio version and the xxx version.  I have renamed by `vcredists` to something like `vcredist_x64_2012_V11.exe`.

[EDIT] Forgot to add earlier that if you are *simply* looking to "install" the missing DLL (as opposed to resolve some bigger set of issues), then you probably won't do any harm by simply installing the relevant vcredist for your architecture (32 bit, 64 bit) and "missing" version.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 x64 released August 2015 - same issue arising. MSVCR110.dll is also found in the sysWOW64 folder (which is where I found it, copying to system32 does not help). To resolve:

1. uninstall the x86 versions of  VC 11 vcredist_x64/86.exe for 2012 and 2013
2. uninstall WAMP Server 2.5
3. delete (maybe back up first) the WAMP folder
4. restart windows
5. reinstall WAMP 2.5

Hopefully like me you have a MySQL database backup handy!