# Installing the newest version of Wamp server

Tags: apache, visual-c++, wampserver, msvcr100.dll

I'm learning PHP and I'm a newbie in apache, mysql,etc.

I tried to install WAMPServer (The current newest version 2.5) but I get the error:

```
msvcr110.dll is missing.
```

I have followed some instructions given here: [WAMP shows error 'MSVCR100.dll' is missing when install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14557245/wamp-shows-error-msvcr100-dll-is-missing-when-install)

However, none of the advice worked for me. I have already installed Visual C++ for windows 32 bits and Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012. After that I installed Visual C++ 2008, it didn't worked either.

And even after that I installed vcredist_x86.exe. This gave me an option to repair my Visual C++, and so I did.

In all my tries I restarted my computer.

I didn't install Visual c++ for windows 64 bits because my os is running a 32 version.

Any ideas?

Thanks for your attention,
berga007

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure you have the latest version of all of these Microsoft C/C++ Redistributable runtime libraries. **You dont need the whole compiler, just these C/C++ runtime libraries.**

The 2008 Redist (32bit) is used by wampmanager even if you installed the 64bit WAMPServer.

The 2010 Redist is used by some versions of Apache ( depending on compiler used ).

The 2012 Redist is used by some versions of Apache ( depending on compiler used ).

**FOR WAMP 32bit**

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=5582)

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=8328)

**If you are using WampServer 2.4/2.5 32bit and therefore Apache 2.4.x**

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 is required](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30679)  And select vcredist_x86.exe

Due to the naming convention used by Microsoft dowmloading these libraries can get a little confusing so download them one at a time and install that download before downloading the next and installing that.

To check that you have all the required runtimes, launch 'Programs and Features' by
Start -> Control Panel -> Programs and Feature

For a 32bit system it should look something like this, ignore the fact that mine has what look like multiple versions of the same library, its just because when you download a newer version it does not remove the older revisions :-

32bit System example

[image]

Comment: sad. Why don't they bundle everything with the installer? I might just use another "wamp alternative"

Comment: Because of the Extortionate Cost of the product. It cost 0.00 pounds, yen, bucks,

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE FOR 2018 (WAMPSERVER 3.x)

You need the following Visual Studio Redistributables:

- 2008
- 2010
- 2012
- 2013
- 2017

Get both the x86 and x64 versions if you're on a x64 machine.

Also, make sure you set skype to NOT use port 80, otherwise WAMP won't start when Skype is open.