# MSVCR110.dll is missing error on wamp running

Tags: visual-c++, wamp, msvcr100.dll

I install the WAMP server on Windows 7 32 bit edition, but when I run this the error comes `MSVCR110.dll is missing`.

I install

> Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package x86 : VC10 SP1 vcredist_x86.exe

from [this location](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8328)

But the problem is still and then i install Visual C++ 2008 [from](http://microsoft.com/en-in/download/confirmation.aspx?id=29)

But the problem is still here. Then I download visual c++ 2012 redistributable
but this is not install in my computer here is a log file
**Log file**

```
[043C:09FC][2014-09-15T15:50:26]: Burn v3.6.3542.0, Windows v6.1 (Build 7600: Service Pack 0), path: C:\Users\azeem\Downloads\vcredist_x64.exe, cmdline: ''
[043C:09FC][2014-09-15T15:50:26]: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\azeem\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_amd64_20140915155026.log'
[043C:09FC][2014-09-15T15:50:26]: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'C:\Users\azeem\Downloads\vcredist_x64.exe'
[043C:09FC][2014-09-15T15:50:27]: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable (x64) - 11.0.61030'
[043C:09FC][2014-09-15T15:50:27]: Detect 2 packages
[043C:09FC][2014-09-15T15:50:27]: Detected package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[043C:09FC][2014-09-15T15:50:27]: Detected package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[043C:09FC][2014-09-15T15:50:27]: Condition 'VersionNT64 >= v6.0 OR (VersionNT64 = v5.2 AND ServicePackLevel >= 1)' evaluates to false.
[043C:09FC][2014-09-15T15:50:27]: Error 0x81f40001: Bundle condition evaluated to false: VersionNT64 >= v6.0 OR (VersionNT64 = v5.2 AND ServicePackLevel >= 1)
[043C:09FC][2014-09-15T15:50:27]: Detect complete, result: 0x0`
```

Comment: I install visual c++ 2012 redistributable from here: http://microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679

Comment: Are you installing the C++ redistributables in chronological order? I.E 2005, 2008, 2010, 2012?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WAMP shows error 'MSVCR100.dll' is missing when install](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14557245/wamp-shows-error-msvcr100-dll-is-missing-when-install)

Answer (score 8):

According to wamp server official website, use the following link [Visual Studio 2012 VC 11 vcredist_x64/86.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679)

Answer (score 0):

Please try to install these. These packages used for only Window 7 32 bit.

1. Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)
2. Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)
3. Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)

Please install first and restart your system then install and start WAMP server.

Comment: `Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)` is not install in my computer see my question.

Comment: Please check below link       
http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,127431
http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,123608

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, none of these answers helped me.
This was due to broken links, mainly.
[This site](http://www.standaloneofflineinstallers.com/2015/12/Microsoft-Visual-C-Redistributable-2015-2013-2012-2010-2008-2005-32-bit-x86-64-bit-x64-Standalone-Offline-Installer-for-Windows.html) helped me out. It has a list of all the redistributables.

**The one that I downloaded and fixed my problem was the 2012 one** as the error is MSVCR110.dll which is **M**icro**s**oft **V**isual **C**++ **R**edistributable Version 20**11**. So I decided that the next redist after 2011 would fix the problem.

I hope this helps others.