# wamp server not running even after installing msvcr110.dll

Tags: php, apache, windows-8, wamp, msvcr100.dll

I installed wamp server 2.5 in my windows 8 laptop but during the process I got error of missing msvcr110.dll. So I googled and found out that some redistributable can be installed from microsoft and then wamp server functions properly. But to my surprise even after that it did not function properly showing the tray icon in yellow where I could not even click.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WAMP shows error 'MSVCR100.dll' is missing when install](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14557245/wamp-shows-error-msvcr100-dll-is-missing-when-install)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After googling for 150 links and trying all processes for 4 hours, I permutated a way to solve this issue. First I had to uninstall wamp and remove all the wamp references and then had to download 2 dlls

1) msvcr110.dll
2) msvcp110.dll

After that I copied them in "C:\Windows\System32". Now I installed the 64 bit wamp as my Laptop is 64 bit. This time I installed wamp without any errors. Even the wamp icon in right bottom tray is green.

Comment: Where did you download those dlls?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this exact same problem by installing Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012. I had already installed Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable 32-bit and 64-bit, but that alone wasn't enough to provide the missing DLL file, despite what so many answers on the Internet claimed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to download this package

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679

PHP needs the x86 version, the x64 version does not work

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem with users of wamp server. The issue is installing the correct version of the VC++ redistributable framework for your system. Is your Win 8 installation on top of a 32bit or 64bit architecture?

Note that wamp 2.5 will require VC11 as well as VC10 (whereas previous versions of wamp only required VC10).

This is discussed here as well: [WAMP shows error 'MSVCR100.dll' is missing when install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14557245/wamp-shows-error-msvcr100-dll-is-missing-when-install)