# WAMP 2.5 not properly seated on the WIN XP 32 BIT Machine

Tags: php, wamp

I have installed " wampserver2.5-Apache-2.4.9-Mysql-5.6.17-php5.5.12-32b " 
Unable to turn on wamp, getting below error.

Installation has done on the Window XP, 32 Bit system

[image]

Comment: See this article.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14557245/wamp-shows-error-msvcr100-dll-is-missing-when-install][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14557245/wamp-shows-error-msvcr100-dll-is-missing-when-install

Comment: You can run WAMPServer 2.4 [Downloadable from here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%202/Wampserver%202.4/) this is fairly new. By the way the reason 2.5 will not run on XP is doen to Microsoft, as the VC2012 runtime will not install on XP as that is needed to run Apache 2.4.9. Its not a WAMPServer limitation so XAMPP etc will also suffer from the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look [here](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,123685). From the docs:

> Wampserver 2.5 will not run on Windows XP

Comment: Actually its Apache 2.4.9 compiled with VC2012 that wont run on XP because the 2012 runtime will not install on XP.