# Installed WAMP on Windows 8 but Failed with MSVCR100.dll Error

Tags: wamp

Starting httpd.exe gives me the system error:

> "The program can't start because MSVCR100.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem."

Can anyone help me fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to have been solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14557383/145279):

> If you are running WAMPServer 2.5 you also need the VC11 redist. Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012
>
> 29.08.2014 with WAMP 2.5
> I agree that VC11 is needed and it is not a bad idea to have previous distributions installed. It will be needed by other application. I am not sure if you need bit 32 version
>
> http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=30679