# Error after installing wamp server3.0.0

Tags: php, wamp

I installed the WAMP Server on my laptop, but after installing it gave me the following **error** :

> "The Program can't start because MSVCR110.dll is missing from your
>   computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem. "

After searching I found that need to install **vcredist_x64 and X86** on my laptop(OS windows 64 bit). I download that but the problem is not solved yet.

Can anybody help me to solve this??

Thanks in Advance

Comment: see this http://superuser.com/questions/886319/do-i-need-install-vcredist-x86-exe-for-64bit-windows-8-1

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14557245/wamp-shows-error-msvcr100-dll-is-missing-when-install).

Comment: i cant get my answer because all links are missing or not longer available