# WAMP apache won't start (port 80 not in use)

Tags: php, apache, laravel, xampp, wamp

Apache won't start in WAMP3 (Windows 10), and I couldn't find any answer here or elsewhere that fixed the problem. So far I've tried the following:

- check if port 80 was in use (see image 1)
- check if world wide web services were turned on in windows (see image 2)
- check "httpd.exe -t" - result "syntax OK"
- I have restarted my computer and wamp several times with no success

Any other suggestions?

**Image of the problem:**

[image: Apache not running]

Image 1:

[image]

Image 2:

[image]

Comment: bro is it this issue. check here!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14557245/wamp-shows-error-msvcr100-dll-is-missing-when-install

Comment: try turning  off skype

Comment: Have a look at the [WAMPServer3 Troubleshooting Doc](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,138295)

Comment: Did you read the Information in the INSTALL Dialog, telling you which MSVC C++ RUntime Libraries you woudl need to check are installed. W10 does not come with all possible MSVC Runtines installed

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Dialog that you are supposed to read and act upon when installing WAMPServer 3

#### --- Installation of Wampserver ---

BEFORE proceeding with the installation of Wampserver, you must ensure that certain elements are installed on your system, otherwise Wampserver will absolutely not run, and in addition, the installation will be faulty and you need to remove Wampserver BEFORE installing the elements that were missing.
Make sure you are "up to date" in the redistributable packages VC9, VC10, VC11, VC13 and VC14

#### See --- Visual C++ Packages below.

- Do not install Wampserver OVER an existing version, follow the advice:

-- Installing a new version of Wampserver: http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,123606

If you install Wampserver over an existing version, not only it will not work, but you risk losing your existing databases.

- Install Wampserver in a folder at the root of a disk, for example C:\wamp or D:\wamp. Use an installation path that does not include spaces or diacritics; Therefore, no installation in `c:\Program Files\` or `C:\ Program Files (x86)\`

You must BEFORE installing, disable or close some applications:

- Close Skype or force not to use port 80
  --Item No. 04 of the [Wampserver TROUBLESHOOTING TIPS:](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,134915)
- Disable IIS
  Item No. 08 of the [Wampserver TROUBLESHOOTING TIPS:](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,134915)

If these prerequisites are not in place, Press the Cancel button to cancel the installation, then apply the prerequisites and restart the installation.

#### --- Visual C++ Packages ---

The MSVC runtime libraries VC9, VC10, VC11 are required for Wampserver 2.4, 2.5 and 3.0, even if you use only Apache and PHP versions with VC11.

Runtimes VC13, VC14 is required for PHP 7 and Apache 2.4.17

- VC9 Packages (Visual C++ 2008 SP1)
  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5582
  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2092
- VC10 Packages (Visual C++ 2010 SP1)
  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8328
  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13523
- VC11 Packages (Visual C++ 2012 Update 4)
  The two files VSU4\vcredist_x86.exe and VSU4\vcredist_x64.exe to be download are on the same page: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679
- VC13 Packages] (Visual C++ 2013[)
  The two files VSU4\vcredist_x86.exe and VSU4\vcredist_x64.exe to be download are on the same page: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784
- VC14 Packages (Visual C++ 2015)
  The two files `vcredist_x86.exe` and `vcredist_x64.exe` to be download are on the same page:
  http://www.microsoft.com/fr-fr/download/details.aspx?id=48145
- If you have a 64-bit Windows, you must install both 32 and 64bit versions, even if you do not use Wampserver 64 bit.
  This is item number 20 of TROUBLESHOOTING TIPS of Wampserver: http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,134915

**You should also remember that WAMPServer must be installed `As an Administrator` and should also be run `As an Administrator`**